# How to get properties file from /WEB-INF folder in JSF?

Tags: jsf, properties, managed-bean, properties-file, web-inf

I have some properties file in `/WEB-INF`. And I want to load it in a JSF managed bean. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use either [`ExternalContext#getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) or [`ExternalContext#getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) wherein you pass the webcontent-relative path.

E.g.:

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
Properties properties = new Properties();
// ...
properties.load(externalContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/file.properties"));
```

This delegates under the covers to `ServletContext#getResource()`/`getResourceAsStream()`.

#### See also:

- [Where to place and how to read configuration resource files in servlet based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-and-how-to-read-properties-files-in-a-jsp-servlet-web-application)

Comment: Could you give me a hint, what classes are subclasses of ExternalContext (ExternalContext is abstract) or where to get externalContext object from?

Comment: @LukaszCzerwinski : ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();

Answer (score 1):

Put it in WEB-INF/classes. That is part of the classpath.

Comment: ...which is not necessary for `ExternalContext#getResource()` methods by the way.

Answer (score 0):

```
     String path="/WEB-INF/list.properties";

    InputStream is=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream(path);
    InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);
```