# Spring Java config and maven variable

Tags: spring, maven

I this XML Spring config using a variable from settings.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="/spring-ds-${usingDb}.xml" />
...
</beans>
```

${usingDb} is from settings.xml maven file

I want to do the same in a Spring java config class

Comment: I think you should look at spring profiles

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301920/passing-maven-properties-to-spring

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way for this is to set key in a properties files like this.

```
database.datasource=${key.datasource}
database.dialect=${key.database.dialect}
....
```

If any one has a better suggestion, you're welcome