# Access maven project version in Spring without filtering

Tags: spring, maven

Using maven, I would like to get the my project version within spring but without filtering. I tried it like this

```
@PropertySource("classpath:META-INF/maven/groupId/artifactId/pom.properties")
```

as proposed here: [Access maven project version in Spring config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886753/access-maven-project-version-in-spring-config-files#3886921)

As written there it is not possible with test or jetty:run. maven is generating the META-INF only in the packaged archive. Is there a way to instruct maven to generate META-INF before so you can start jetty:run, let spring read the project version from manifest without getting an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just for test purposes, you could just create a `pom.properties` sample file in the `src/webapp/META-INF/..../` directory in your source tree?

Cheers,

Comment: That seems to be fine as I can mimic the behaviour at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the version number in a `project.properties` file also and then access the version number from the project.properties file in the java code. Hope this helps you.

Comment: thx, but of course I don't want to maintain the version number at a different place than my pom file.