# How to read value in property file in applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven, caching

I want to define dynamic mvc:resource in applicationContext.xml as in code below, which should  either take property through Maven or read property (in my case application/project version) from any property file

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/${project.version}/**" location="/static/"/>
```

is there any way to read property value in  applicationContext.xml as in above statment? I need to fix this in order to bust caching if new build deployed.

Comment: nope its not duplicate, here i want to read property in applicationContext.xml

Comment: I cannot try it now, you could try the `context:property-placeholder` with the property and make the resource: `<mvc:resources mapping="/static/" + ${project.version} + "/**" location="/static/"/>`. Its worth a shot I guess.

Comment: oops!. My mistake. Can you try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886753/access-maven-project-version-in-spring-config-files)

Comment: @WilliamCallahan thats what i need, however filtering is one the solution it not working in my case. But reading from property file is another good idea.