# How to reach pom.properties

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am trying to get application's version and name/artifact-id from server at runtime for the plugin I am developing.
I know I can get the details from pom.properties that is generated on the server, using below code

```
java.io.InputStream inputStream = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/maven/<application-directory-structure>/pom.properties");
Properties mavenProperties= new Properties();
mavenProperties.load(inputStream );
String version = (String) mavenProperties.get("version");
String name = (String) mavenProperties.get("artifactId");
```

But I am not able to reach to the pom.properties.
I tried using `JarFile.getEntries()`but as I am not able to get the name of the war at runtime, its not working.
Any suggestions how I can get the details I am looking for?
I can't modify the maven plugin to get the artifact details. I am making a plugin myself and can't force all the apps for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Maven Artifact version at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712970/how-to-get-maven-artifact-version-at-runtime)

Comment: Possibly but as it says one needs to modify the <archive> config in order to write the details. Also I am trying to find from war and it gives from Jar. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @SandiipPatil AFAIC a WAR has the same internal format as a JAR, it just has a different file extension. As said [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-archive-configuration.html) the <archive/> config should also work with WARs.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this link could help you: http://technotes.tostaky.biz/2012/08/understanding-absolute-and-relative.html

ps: Understanding Absolute and Relative Path with getResourceAsStream()

Answer (score 0):

A little late maybe, but for the record: I got something like this to work by:

-NOT prefixing a leading slash ("/"), and
-using Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...) and
-use the maven groupId and artifactId

Example

`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/maven/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/pom.properties");`