# Getting application version from pom

Tags: java, spring, maven, versioning

I have a rest endpoint used to return information about application (so far only app version)
But so far this info is hardcoded, and it's pretty easy to forget to change it.
I will be better to retrieve app version from pom or manifest file. Is there any project that brings such functionality?

Comment: Do you mean to say version of the build ? If yes then simply add <version>1.0.0</version> in the POM

Comment: I think he means how does he then read that version at runtime... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712970/how-to-get-maven-artifact-version-at-runtime

Comment: Yes I would like to read current version (value of <version> tag) from pom and use it in java code. And I want to do it in simple and elegant way

Comment: Just take a look [here](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2014/01/02/version-information-into-your-appas-with-maven/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is amazing project named [Appinfo](http://appinfo.sf.net/), please use it and enjoy! (It has an ugly page, I know - but it works :)

> > AppInfo allows to automatically feed your application with a current version number, build date or build number.

---

Also excellent [Spring Boot Actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready) provides feature named [Info Endpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-application-info-env) which can publish version information to web or REST.

> > By default the Actuator adds an /info endpoint to the main server. It contains the commit and timestamp information from git.properties (if that file exists) and also any properties it finds in the environment with prefix "info".

Answer (score 15):

Spring Boot can refer to the project version defined in pom.xml and expose it via REST using [Actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-application-info-env):

```
# application.properties
endpoints.info.enabled=true
info.app.version=@project.version@
```

Then accessing the /info URL (e.g. http://localhost:8080/info) will return:

```
{"app": {"version": "<major.minor.incremental>"}}
```

See also: [spring boot/spring web app embedded version number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772726/spring-boot-spring-web-app-embedded-version-number)

Answer (score 13):

You better use build-in manifest.

```
new Manifest(Application.class.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/manifest.mf"))
```

For the concrete impl-version:

```
new Manifest(Application.class.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/manifest.mf"))
            .getMainAttributes()
            .get(Attributes.Name.IMPLEMENTATION_VERSION)
```

Using maven do not forget to create the manifest using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: This does didn't work with my pring-boot application. the manifest was found but was belonging to one of my project's lib

Comment: Was looking for a solution for so long. Thanks, works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [resource filtering](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-description.html) of maven or something like the `maven-substitute-plugin`.

Comment: Yes, but howto integrate filtering with REST? :)

Comment: When building the project with Maven, the requested version-information will go into some file (again it is somehow "hardcoded", but set by the resource-preprocessor of maven before building the project) - like a Properties-file or directly in Java-class, ... The application can use this information then to return it on REST-request.
Am I missing something?

Comment: This is true, but there are tools for doing this even easier.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't sound too difficult to do this "manually". But it sounds interesting. Thanks for the hint.