# How to read manifest.mf from *.war/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file?

Tags: java, spring, maven, web-applications

Using maven get compiled *.war file, which contains:

```
- META-INF
- - MANIFEST.MF
- WEB-INF
- - classes
- - lib
- - web.xml
```

Using java.util.jar.Manifest I want to read the manifest file to get application version from there like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21046257/1728511

But `Application.class.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/manifest.mf")` returns `null`.

`Application.class.getResource( "" ).getFile()` returns `%WAR%/WEB-INF/lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar!/javax/ws/rs/core/`

Using Spring, I've implemented ApplicationContextAware interface to get ApplicationContext instance.

And `applicationContext.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( "" )` returns `%WAR%/WEB-INF/classes`.

But I don't need `WEB-INF`, I need `META-INF` directory. How to get it?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that  each `.jar` in your `.war` can contain a `/META-INF`?

Comment: @DirkLachowski, so how can it help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing cases. Your `META-INF` contains a `MANIFEST.MF` but you are trying to open a resource stream on `manifest.mf`.

You will have to change

```
Application.class.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/manifest.mf")
```

to

```
Application.class.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem was - it was case sensitive.

Comment: @Kefirchiks You are welcome, please feel free to vote up.