# display application version in title using thymeleaf and springboot

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I want to display in my htm page the version of my webapp, using something like this (thymeleaf inside) :

```
<h4 th:text="${version}">Version</h4>
```

The data is well set in the pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>fr.test.navig</groupId>
    <artifactId>navigo</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
...
<!-- Package as an executable jar -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Application</mainClass>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            true
                        </addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and I can see it in the MANIFEST.MF (which is in the generated jar under META-INF) :

> Implementation-Version: 2.0.3-SNAPSHOT

I've tried to get the appplication version in the controller and set it in a ModuleAttribute :

```
@ModelAttribute("version")
public String getVersion() {
    logger.info("ModelAttribute to get application version");
    return getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
}
```

But `getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion()` value is `null`. Indeed the package implementationVersion is not the implementation Version of the application by default.

Comment: Don't have an exact answer but here are a couple links that may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697449/retrieve-version-from-maven-pom-xml-in-code and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045007/getting-application-version-from-pom

Comment: @RobBaily I've read it before asking. The solution I tried is my interpretation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697449/retrieve-version-from-maven-pom-xml-in-code answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simplest way I've found : 
In my controller :

```
@ModelAttribute("version")
public String getVersion() throws IOException {
    logger.info("ModelAttribute to get application version");
    Manifest manif = new Manifest(
            Application.class.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"));
    String version = (String) manif.getMainAttributes().get(
            Attributes.Name.IMPLEMENTATION_VERSION);
    return version;
}
```

In my htm page :

```
<h4 th:text="${version}">Version</h4>
```

Answer (score 12):

I know I'm late but [Patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41951861/how-to-do-the-application-versioning-in-the-spring-boot) and Spring docs greatly helps in this matter.

**1.** If your *pom.xml* use *spring-boot-starter-parent* as parent, you can use `@project.version@` to get version (and any other Maven properties) in your *application.properties* file. According to Spring docs:

> You can automatically expand properties from the Maven project using
>   resource filtering. If you use the spring-boot-starter-parent you 
>     can
>   then refer to your Maven ‘project properties’ via @..@ placeholders

Maven **pom.xml**:

```
<groupId>com.foo</groupId>
<artifactId>bar</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Foo</name>
<description>Bar</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Spring **application.properties**:

```
foo.app.version=@project.version@
```

**2.** Then a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` can be used to inject version as model attribute.

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerAdvice {

    @Value("${foo.app.version}")
    private String applicationVersion;

    @ModelAttribute("applicationVersion")
    public String getApplicationVersion() {
        return applicationVersion;
    }

}
```

**3.** Finally this model attribute can be accessed by Thymeleaf as any other.

```html
<th:block th:text="${applicationVersion}"></th:block>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will work but it is not necessary. Just enable resource filtering in your pom and put @project.version@ in the Thymeleaf template.

Comment: A bit simpler, omit 2. and in 3. use `${@environment.getProperty("foo.app.version")}` instead. And if your not using spring-boot-starter-parent, take a look here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure resource plugin to activate filtering on the file that need to be enriched with properties coming from your POM file.

In the generated war, the version (in fact `${project.version}`) will be hardcoded to your POM version.

Comment: I've added   <resources>
   <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
   </resource>
  </resources> , but it doesn't work better, is it what you suggested or was it more specific to the htm file by instance?

Comment: I guess that your HTML file is not inside `src/main/resources`. If you want to apply filter on it, you should add the `src/main/webapp/hmtl`(or something like that) to the resources configuration

Comment: My htm is in `src/main/resources/templates`. I've changed the path in the pom,  but it doesn't work better. And as the use is in the htm file, there is no error, just no value : instead of `<h4 >2.0.3-SNAPSHOT</h4>` or at list `<h4></h4>`, I have nothing at all in the source generated.

Comment: `@project.version@` is what you want.