# How to do the application versioning in the spring boot?

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot, versioning

I am using `spring boot` and `gradle` for my application. The application can have different `versions` and we need to show this version info on the application in the footer.

e.g. `1.0.0 or 1.0.0.RELEASE etc`

what are the possible ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good example in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-automatic-expansion-gradle). You can automatically expand properties from the Gradle project and refer those properties as placeholders in your `application.properties` file.

> ```
>  processResources {
>      expand(project.properties) 
>  }
> ```
>
> You can then refer to your Gradle project’s properties via
>   placeholders, e.g.
>
> ```
> app.name=${name} 
> app.description=${description}
> ```

You are then able to use for example the `@Value` annotation to get the `properties` value in your application.

```
@Value("${app.version}")
public String appVersion;

@Override
public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(appVersion);
}
```

Maybe you have to escape the placeholder mechanism:

> Gradle’s expand method uses Groovy’s SimpleTemplateEngine which
>   transforms `${..}` tokens. The `${..}` style conflicts with Spring’s own
>   property placeholder mechanism. To use Spring property placeholders
>   together with automatic expansion the Spring property placeholders
>   need to be escaped like `\${..}`.

P.S.:With maven you can do the same. [more...](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-automatic-expansion-maven)

Comment: I tried what u suggested. But then I am getting error like Execution failed for task ':processResources'.

Could not copy file .. logback.xml

Comment: @ashishjmeshram maybe you have to escape the placeholders. I updated my answer. If the error still exists, please provide some more infos.

Comment: The problem is with processResources { expand(project.properties)} line only. So even if I just add this one line only. I start getting errors.

Comment: @ashishjmeshram can you show your error messages you get.

Comment: The error I am getting is as below. :processResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processResources'.
> Could not copy file '/opt/workspaces/src/main/resources/logback-spring.xml' to '/opt//workspaces/build/resources/main/logback-spring.xml'.

Comment: Also, I am using yml file and this is how I am trying to reference the gradle properties in my yml file . version: ${version}. See if this is correct or not?