# How to get implementation version when project is built with Gradle

Tags: gradle

When project is built with `Maven` it is possible to get implementation version like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712970/how-to-get-maven-artifact-version-at-runtime).
Is it possible to do that or something with Gradle?

I moved from Maven to Gradle with my app.
With Maven build I was able to display application version like `Application vX.X.X` where `X.X.X` was retrieved from implementation version. It that possible with Gradle?
Basically I want that version was resolved automatically.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you want to achieve?

Comment: Define "implementation version". Show code if you can't define it.

Comment: Version described in project's `pom.xml` like <version>1.5.4</version>. And it's retrieval like described in linked question.

Comment: So, you would like to write the project name and version in the manifest file of the jar generated by Gradle, is that what you're asking? If so, see http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N12907

Comment: I second the link from @JBNizet. groupid you'll have to create yourself in parent build.gradle or subproject. ArtifactId=name, or something you yourself define. Apart from that I like this presentation regarding Gradle and devops: https://speakerdeck.com/bmuschko/building-a-continuous-delivery-pipeline-with-gradle-and-jenkins

Comment: If someone would put that up as an answer I would gladly accept it - cause it worked just fine.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As  @JB Nizet suggested solution can be found [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#other_convention_properties).

Comment: [THIS LINK](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sub:manifest) has an updated anchor that should work, and looks a little more durable. If the anchor breaks, info is in the Manifest subsection under the Jar task.

Answer (score 10):

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes('Main-Class':             'Your main class',
                   'Implementation-Title':   'Your title',
                   'Implementation-Version': 'You version')
    }
}
```

or if you use `shadowJar`

```
shadowJar {
        manifest {
            attributes 'Main-Class':             'Your main class'
            attributes 'Implementation-Title':   'Your title'
            attributes 'Implementation-Version': 'You version'
        }
    }
```

Then in the java sources you could use:

```
getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion()
getClass().getPackage().getImplementationTitle()
```

See more info in the Gradle doc: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sub:manifest