# Get jar version in runtime

Tags: java, reflection, jar

I'm wondering if it is possible to retrieve, in runtime, a version number of a jar from which the class comes from?

I know its possible to find jar from which the class comes from:

```
MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

but what about a version?

(assuming its not in the file name:) )

Comment: Jars don't have versions.

Comment: yes, you are right, version belong to library version but in slang it's 'take jar version x.y.z'

Comment: s.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion() - could be null in Java 8.

Comment: to include implementation version in manifest, you have to modify the <archive> configuration element of the maven-jar-plugin and set addDefaultImplementationEntries and addDefaultSpecificationEntries to true. This will fix s.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion() become null

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;

/**
Display package name and version information for javax.mail.internet.
*/
public final class ReadVersion {
  public static void main(String... aArgs){
    ReadVersion readVersion = new ReadVersion();
    readVersion.readVersionInfoInManifest();
  }

  public void readVersionInfoInManifest(){
    InternetAddress object = new InternetAddress();
    Package objPackage = object.getClass().getPackage();
    //examine the package object 
    String name = objPackage.getSpecificationTitle();
    String version = objPackage.getSpecificationVersion();
    //some jars may use 'Implementation Version' entries in the manifest instead
    System.out.println("Package name: " + name);
    System.out.println("Package version: " + version);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're using maven to build the JAR, `objPackage.getSpecificationVersion()` might give 'null' as the version.
to fix that, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712970/get-maven-artifact-version-at-runtime

Answer (score 29):

Try this, it may be helpful:

```
String s = new String();
System.out.println(s.getClass().getPackage().getSpecificationVersion());
System.out.println(s.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion());
```

Output:

```
1.7
1.7.0_25
```

Answer (score 6):

Be careful using getPackage().getImplementationVersion/getSpecificationVersion()

getSpecificationVersion returns specVersion from Manifest.
Manifest is a property of a jar and is used in sun.misc.URLClassPath as

```
  public Manifest getManifest() throws IOException {
                    SharedSecrets.javaUtilJarAccess().ensureInitialization(JarLoader.this.jar);
                    return JarLoader.this.jar.getManifest();
                }
```

So in case somebody use your library as dependency for fat jar, it returns the version of Manifest for fat jar.

Comment: You have just highlighted an important reason not to make fat jars:  it wipes out individual libraries’ manifest information.