# Identify version of Joda-Time library currently in use, at runtime

Tags: java, jodatime

Does [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) offer a method to identify its version?

For debugging, logging, and such, it would be nice to identify the version of Joda-Time in use at runtime.

I tried using Google to search the doc (`site:www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/ version`), but did not find the desired method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724145/get-jar-version-in-runtime

Answer (score 1):

If your Joda Time contains Maven information, you can use the following code to extract the version:

```
String version = null;
try (InputStream in = DateTime.class.getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/maven/joda-time/joda-time/pom.properties")) {
    if (in != null) {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(in);
        version = p.getProperty("version");
    }
} catch (IOException ignore) {}
System.out.println(version);
```