# Gradle: Determine actually used library version when using '+'

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my Gradle script I'm using some library dependecies like

```
implementation "com.example:myLibrary:+"
```

I now want to display in the app which version acutally is used. The easiest way for this would be using a `BuildConfigField` which holds the version information. But how can I find out which version gradle acutally downloads. Is there a way to determine this in `gradle` or do I have to extract it from the path as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724145/get-jar-version-in-runtime)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
configurations.implementation.filter { it.name.contains('myLibrary') }.each { 
    println 'version : ' + it.name.take(it.name.lastIndexOf('.')).split('-').last()
}
```

Comment: `implementation` does not work with current gradle Versions. But it's a good start to continue from. Thanks for that.

Comment: In newer Gradle versions `Resolving configuration 'implementation' directly is not allowed`