# Accessing JUnit version during runtime

Tags: junit5

Is there a way to access the JUnit5 version during runtime?

E.g.

```
    ...
    System.out.printf( "JUnit: %s\n",  junit.runner.Version.id() );
    ...
```

worked fine for JUnit4.

I am looking for the "counterpart" for JUnit5

THANKS :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is no single "JUnit 5" version number.

There are [three](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#overview-what-is-junit-5) of them. They are listed on [junit.org](https://junit.org/junit5/):

[image]

All artifacts of these three groups contain version information packaged

a) into their module descriptor and

b) into their manifest files.

For **Jupiter** for example, you may use

a)  `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test.class.getModule().getDescriptor().getVersion()`

or b) `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()`

to access **Jupiter**'s version information at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, but I am still having problems.
E.g. I can not access ".getVersion()"

Anyway

```
...
import java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor;
import java.lang.module.ModuleDescriptor.Version;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
...
String getJupiterVersionFromModuleDescriptor(){
    final Class<Test> clazz = org.junit.jupiter.api.Test.class;
    final Module module = clazz.getModule();
    final ModuleDescriptor moduleDescriptor = module.getDescriptor();
    final Optional<Version> optionalVersion = moduleDescriptor.version();
    final Version version = optionalVersion.get();
    return version.toString();
}

String String getPlatformVersionFromModuleDescriptor(){
    final Class<JUnitPlatform> clazz = org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform.class;
    final Module module = clazz.getModule();
    final ModuleDescriptor moduleDescriptor = module.getDescriptor();
    final Optional<Version> optionalVersion = moduleDescriptor.version();
    final Version version = optionalVersion.get();
    return version.toString();
}

String getJupiterVersionFromManifest(){
    final Class<Test> clazz = org.junit.jupiter.api.Test.class;
    final Package pakage = clazz.getPackage();
    final String version = pakage.getImplementationVersion();
    return version;
}

String getPlatformVersionFromManifest(){
    final Class<JUnitPlatform> clazz = org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform.class;
    final Package pakage = clazz.getPackage();
    final String version = pakage.getImplementationVersion();
    return version;
}// delivers null in my case - getPlatformVersionFromModuleDescriptor() reports 1.5.1 on my machine
```

works and of course:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.Test.class.getModule().getDescriptor().version()
org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform.class.getModule().getDescriptor().version()
org.junit.jupiter.api.Test.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()
org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()
```

works also.

Currently I am using:

```
String getJupiterVersion(){
    final Class<Test> testClass = org.junit.jupiter.api.Test.class;
    final Optional<Version> optionalVersion = testClass.getModule().getDescriptor().version();
    return optionalVersion.isPresent() ? optionalVersion.get().toString() : testClass.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
}

String getPlatformVersion(){
    final Class<JUnitPlatform> jUnitPlatformClass = org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform.class;
    final Optional<Version> optionalVersion = jUnitPlatformClass.getModule().getDescriptor().version();
    return optionalVersion.isPresent() ? optionalVersion.get().toString() : jUnitPlatformClass.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
}
```

Further: [Get jar version in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724145/get-jar-version-in-runtime) might be helpful.

Anyway, I am still having problems to access the vintage version.
E.g. org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine is not accessible ???

And just recently on some machine running JUnit 5.4 getDescriptor() resp. e.g. org.junit.jupiter.api.Test.class.getModule().getDescriptor() delivered null.
I like to have a way of identifying the JUnit version that runs on any JUnit 5 installation.