# Get maven properties at build time

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm trying to get some properties from the `pom.xml` at build time based on the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_filter_resource_files).

My goal is to inject them in my Spring boot `application.properties` but the properties are not replaced.

Here's my code

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>xx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xx</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>xx</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <type>jar</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
            </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
        <finalName>xx</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins> 
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>static</directory>
                <targetPath>static</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources> 
</build>
```

**src\main\resources\application.properties**

```
application.version=${project.version}
```

Am I missing something?  Is this supposed to work?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto `application.version=${pom.version}` in **/target/classes/application.properties**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using the spring boot parent pom the default placeholders have been re-configured to not conflict with the ${} syntax of spring itself.

To replace the maven properties use @ - so @project.version@ instead of ${project.version}.

filtering of the application.properties file is enabled by default.

Comment: I have been looking for this solution for months and finally got here. Thanks!