# How can I reference the artifactId in the pom from my java code in a maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I am very new to java. I am creating a maven plugin that needs to know the `artifactId` from the pom. It will use this name to create a directory. I have searched the web for `"resource"` and `"filtering"`, the `environment variable`, configuration setup, etc. but have not found anything useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting maven project version and artifact ID from pom while running in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551439/getting-maven-project-version-and-artifact-id-from-pom-while-running-in-eclipse)

Comment: What kind of problem should your plugin solve? Can you explain that more in detail?

Comment: The article suggested above "Getting maven project version and artifact ID" looks really helpful except that I get an error on the line "properties.load(this.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("project.properties"));". "this" is not allowed. Should I substitute something else for "this"?

Comment: What my plugin is supposed to do is this: The artifactId is something like AAA. My plugin needs to create a directory called AAA and find all the other directories in this area (called aaaDir1, aaaDir2, etc.) and copy the content of these other directories into the AAA directory.