# Maven resource filtering: get license information

Tags: java, maven, properties-file

I want to generate a resource file containing information from `pom.xml` that I can then load in my Java application. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697449/retrieve-version-from-maven-pom-xml-in-code) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551439/getting-maven-project-version-and-artifact-id-from-pom-while-running-in-eclipse/26573884#26573884). I can generate `.properties` file with some information substituted but not license information.

I have this section in my `pom.xml`:

```
<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>MIT license</name>
        <url>https://spdx.org/licenses/MIT.html</url>
        <distribution>manual</distribution>
        <comments>A short and to the point license that allows almost anything</comments>
    </license>
</licenses>
```

And then I want to do this:

```
licenseName = ${project.licenses.license.name}
licenseUrl = ${project.licenses.license.url}
```

but the values do not get replaced.

Googling suggests using some plugins that handle licenses, but that is too much for my use case.

Thank you.

Comment: Just a wild guess: You maybe need to specify that you want the first license from the list.

Comment: The licenses is a list of license so you have to specify which one you like to access `${project.licenses[0].name}` (not 100% sure if that way..)..

Comment: I was thinking that may be it, but I cannot find how to do that. License plugins or resource management plugins always pop up when serching online. I might be missing the correct terminology. Could you please provide a link at the very least since I cannot find suitable sources of information?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to try? Get all licenses into a file? For example: https://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/

Comment: Sorry, I had written that previous comment before @khmarbaise wrote theirs. And the suggestion does not work. I want to load the name and the url to code so I can display it in "about" window of my app.

Comment: The license plugin creates an XML which you can simply parse and use it... and will do what you want during the build process..

Comment: Thanks, I will consider that, but it still seems to me that the most effective way would be figuring out this indexing thing, but I cannot find any information on how to do it.

Comment: I don't think so because every time you change the licensing (change add a dependency) You build setup needs to be changed as well. If you simply run the license plugin which generates an xml file which can be packaged into the app and read and it does not matter how many entries are in there...

Comment: Ok, I will give it a go.