# Get (maven) artifact version at runtime of Java 9+ modular application

Tags: java, maven, java-module, jlink

I have a Java 11 application which I develop using Maven and in the pom.xml I have a version declared.

```xml
<groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
<artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
<version>0.1.2.3</version>
```

I want to get this version at runtime e.g. using `getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion()` as it's described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712970/get-maven-artifact-version-at-runtime). This works as long as I don't package my application as a modular runtime image using Jlink. Then I only get `null` returned from above call.

I package my application using:

```sh
jlink --output target/artifact-image --module-path target/dependencies --launcher MyApp=my.module.name/my.main.Class --add-modules my.module.name
```

Jlink has actually a parameter `--version` but this returns the Jlink version instead setting it for the generated artifact.

**So, how can I get the version (of my Maven project) at runtime?**

- How to define it in the modular application?
- How to get it into the modular application?
- How to read it in the modular application?

I know I could define it in a resource file and simply read it from there, however I prefer to have it only in the `pom.xml` (= to have a single source of truth).

Comment: try this `getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion()`

Comment: have you looked into this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697449/retrieve-version-from-maven-pom-xml-in-code/41791885

Comment: You could add the version when packaging the artifact with `jar --module-version=VERSION`. Not sure how to specify that with maven through.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did this using the filtering function of the [Maven Resources Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

First, enable filtering in the pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Then add a `src/main/resources/my-version.properties` file containig:

```
my.version=${project.version}
```

So you can use the following code in Java:

```
Properties myProperties = new Properties();
try {
    myProperties.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/my-version.properties"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
}
String theVersion = Objects.requireNonNull((String) myProperties.get("my.version"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my last job. I needed to get the version for modules/jars that are not a direct dependency of the application, as well as the module's version itself. The classpath is assembled from multiple modules when the application starts, the main application module has no knowledge of how many jars are added later.

That's why I came up with a different solution, which may be a little more elegant than having to read XML or properties from jar files.

## The idea

1. use a Java service loader approach to be able to add as many components/artifacts later, which can contribute their own versions at runtime. Create a very lightweight library with just a few lines of code to read, find, filter and sort all of the artifact versions on the classpath.
2. Create a maven source code generator plugin that generates the service implementation for each of the modules at compile time, package a very simple service in each of the jars.

## The solution

Part one of the solution is the `artifact-version-service` library, which can be found on [github](https://github.com/swesteme/artifact-version-service) and [MavenCentral](https://search.maven.org/artifact/de.westemeyer/artifact-version-service) now. It covers the service definition and a few ways to get the artifact versions at runtime.

Part two is the `artifact-version-maven-plugin`, which can also be found on [github](https://github.com/swesteme/artifact-version-maven-plugin) and [MavenCentral](https://search.maven.org/artifact/de.westemeyer/artifact-version-maven-plugin). It is used to have a hassle-free generator implementing the service definition for each of the artifacts.

## Examples

#### Fetching all modules with coordinates

No more reading jar manifests or property files, just a simple method call:

```java
// iterate list of artifact dependencies
for (Artifact artifact : ArtifactVersionCollector.collectArtifacts()) {
    // print simple artifact string example
    System.out.println("artifact = " + artifact);
}
```

A sorted set of artifacts is returned. To modify the sorting order, provide a custom comparator:

```java
new ArtifactVersionCollector(Comparator.comparing(Artifact::getVersion)).collect();
```

This way the list of artifacts is returned sorted by version numbers.

#### Find a specific artifact

```java
ArtifactVersionCollector.findArtifact("de.westemeyer", "artifact-version-service");
```

Fetches the version details for a specific artifact.

#### Find artifacts with matching groupId(s)

Find all artifacts with groupId `de.westemeyer` (exact match):

```java
ArtifactVersionCollector.findArtifactsByGroupId("de.westemeyer", true);
```

Find all artifacts where groupId *starts with* `de.westemeyer`:

```java
ArtifactVersionCollector.findArtifactsByGroupId("de.westemeyer", false);
```

Sort result by version number:

```java
new ArtifactVersionCollector(Comparator.comparing(Artifact::getVersion)).artifactsByGroupId("de.", false);
```

#### Implement custom actions on list of artifacts

By supplying a lambda, the very first example could be implemented like this:

```java
ArtifactVersionCollector.iterateArtifacts(a -> {
    System.out.println(a);
    return false;
});
```

## Installation

Add these two tags to all `pom.xml` files, or maybe to a company master pom somewhere:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>de.westemeyer</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifact-version-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>generate-service</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>de.westemeyer</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact-version-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

## Feedback

It would be great if you could give the solution a try. Getting feedback about whether you think the solution fits your needs would be even better. So please don't hesitate to add a new issue on any of the github projects if you have any suggestions, feature requests, problems, whatsoever.

## Licence

All of the source code is open source, free to use even for commercial products (MIT licence).