# How to read file from relative path in Java project? java.io.File cannot find the path specified

Tags: java, file

I have a project with 2 packages:

1. `tkorg.idrs.core.searchengines`
2. `tkorg.idrs.core.searchengines`

In package (2) I have a text file `ListStopWords.txt`, in package (1) I have a class `FileLoadder`. Here is code in `FileLoader`:

```
File file = new File("properties\\files\\ListStopWords.txt");
```

But I have this error:

> The system cannot find the path specified

Can you give a solution to fix it?

Comment: Your both package examples are the same. Don't you mean `properties.files` for `2`?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

If it's already in the classpath, then just obtain it from the classpath instead of from the disk file system. Don't fiddle with relative paths in `java.io.File`. They are dependent on the current working directory over which you have totally no control from inside the Java code.

Assuming that `ListStopWords.txt` is in the same package as your `FileLoader` class, then do:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("ListStopWords.txt");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
```

Or if all you're ultimately after is actually an `InputStream` of it:

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("ListStopWords.txt");
```

This is certainly preferred over creating a `new File()` because the `url` may not necessarily represent a disk file system path, but it could also represent virtual file system path (which may happen when the JAR is expanded into memory instead of into a temp folder on disk file system) or even a network path which are both not per definition digestable by `File` constructor.

If the file is -as the package name hints- is *actually* a fullworthy [properties file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) (containing `key=value` lines) with just the "wrong" extension, then you could feed the `InputStream` immediately to the [`load()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) method.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("ListStopWords.txt"));
```

Note: when you're trying to access it from inside `static` context, then use `FileLoader.class` (or whatever `YourClass.class`) instead of `getClass()` in above examples.

Comment: Was FileLoader removed from java? I am trying to do this from a static context (java 6) and I can't find any way to import it and it keeps telling me it cannot resolve to a type.  Strangely enough, it autocompleted as I typed it, but then proceeded to give me an error.

Comment: oh, it's supposed to be ClassLoader.class.

Comment: @turbo: `FileLoader` is OP's own custom class. It's supposed to be exactly that class wherein you're attempting to obtain the resource. Thus, so `NameOfYourCurrentClass.class.getResourceAsStream(...)`. The `ClassLoader.class` will fail if the `ClassLoader` class is being loaded by a different classloader, which may happen in an "enterprise" application with a hierarchy of multiple classloaders (like a Java EE web application).

Comment: Ohh, I see. I didn't understand that it was dependent.  Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: It might be better to do following:
Scanner scan = new Scanner(url.getPath());
  content = scan.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
   scan.close();

Comment: Any suggestion for if the file is not in the same package? In my instance I'm trying to open a file which is located in a test package.

Comment: Head to https://stackoverflow.com/q/2161054 for elaborate examples on them.

Answer (score 86):

The relative path works in Java using the `.` specifier.

- `.` means same folder as the currently running context.
- `..` means the parent folder of the currently running context.

So the question is how do you know the path where the Java is currently looking?

Do a small experiment

```
   File directory = new File("./");
   System.out.println(directory.getAbsolutePath());
```

Observe the output, you will come to know the current directory where Java is looking. From there, simply use the `./` specifier to locate your file.

For example if the output is

> G:\JAVA8Ws\MyProject\content.

and your file is present in the folder "MyProject" simply use

```
File resourceFile = new File("../myFile.txt");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: after hours of searching this answer provided me with the solution

Answer (score 47):

The following line can be used if we want to specify the relative path of the file.

```
File file = new File("./properties/files/ListStopWords.txt");
```

Comment: may i know why 3 slashes between the path.

Comment: Error: > Illegal escape character in string literal.

Comment: How to convert this to an `InputStream`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky `InputStream is = new FileInputStream("./properties/files/ListStopWords.txt");`

Answer (score 10):

```
InputStream in = FileLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("<relative path from this class to the file to be read>");
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky its the name of Class. You can refer to `.class` literal only by providing full name of its class.

Comment: I think it intends to be FileLoader.

Answer (score 6):

try `.\properties\files\ListStopWords.txt`

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Assuming you want to read from `resources` directory in `FileSystem` class.

```
String file = "dummy.txt";
var path = Paths.get("src/com/company/fs/resources/", file);
System.out.println(path);

System.out.println(Files.readString(path));
```

**Note:** Leading `.` is not needed.

Answer (score 5):

I could have commented but I have less rep for that.
Samrat's answer did the job for me. It's better to see the current directory path through the following code.

```
    File directory = new File("./");
    System.out.println(directory.getAbsolutePath());
```

I simply used it to rectify an issue I was facing in my project. Be sure to use ./ to back to the parent directory of the current directory.

```
    ./test/conf/appProperties/keystore
```

Comment: I'm running my code through tomcat and so the current directory is not the project folder - How do i define the relative path to the project root?

Im currently using the hard path:"C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Repositories\\L1_WebShop\\dblogs.log";

Comment: @TiagoRedaelli check out this ques : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843217/how-to-get-relative-path-of-current-directory-in-tomcat-from-linux-environment-u

Answer (score 4):

While the answer provided by BalusC works for this case, it will break when the file path contains spaces because in a URL, these are being converted to %20 which is not a valid file name. If you construct the File object using a URI rather than a String, whitespaces will be handled correctly:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("ListStopWords.txt");
File file = new File(url.toURI());
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to parse 'command.json' inside src/main//js/Simulator.java. For that I copied json file in src folder and gave the absolute path like this :

```
Object obj  = parser.parse(new FileReader("./src/command.json"));
```

Answer (score 1):

For me actually the problem is the File object's class path is from `<project folder path> or ./src`, so use `File file = new File("./src/xxx.txt");` solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked with -

```
    String token = "";
    File fileName = new File("filename.txt").getAbsoluteFile();
    Scanner inFile = null;
    try {
        inFile = new Scanner(fileName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while( inFile.hasNext() )
    {
        String temp = inFile.next( );  
        token = token + temp;
    }
    inFile.close(); 
    
    System.out.println("file contents" +token);
```

Answer (score 1):

This option is defininitely the best:

```java
URL url = getClass().getResource("ListStopWords.txt");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
```

Worked great for me!
However, it translates `" "` to `"%20"`, this is a problem.

URL is deprecated now!
Use URI instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to call `getClass()` from Static method or static block, the you can do the following way.

You can call `getClass()` on the `Properties` object you are loading into.

```
    public static Properties pathProperties = null;
    
    static { 
        pathProperties = new Properties();
        String pathPropertiesFile = "/file.xml";
//      Now go for getClass() method
        InputStream paths = pathProperties.getClass().getResourceAsStream(pathPropertiesFile);
    }
```

Comment: Simply missing a closing quote.

Answer (score 0):

If text file is not being read, try using a more closer absolute path (if you wish 
you could use complete absolute path,) like this:

```
FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("\\Dash\\src\\RS\\Test.txt");
```

assume that the absolute path is:

```
C:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Dash\\src\\RS\\Test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

String basePath = new File("myFile.txt").getAbsolutePath();
this basepath you can use as the correct path of your file

Answer (score 0):

if you want to load property file from resources folder which is available inside src folder, use this

```java
String resourceFile = "resources/db.properties";
InputStream resourceStream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceFile);
Properties p=new Properties();  
p.load(resourceStream);  
      
    System.out.println(p.getProperty("db"));
```

db.properties files contains key and value `db=sybase`

Answer (score 0):

May be your sturcture is like this [enter image description here][1]
main

- java

  - filesystem

    - FileLoader.java
  - resource

    - 1.txt

And you can get the file 1.txt through some methods, here are some cases

```java
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //1 you can use Path class
        Path path = Paths.get("src/main/java/resource/1.txt");
        System.out.println(path.toAbsolutePath());
        // and you can convert path to a file , then you ge file object.
        File file = path.toFile();
        System.out.println(" ------------- 2  ----------------");
        //2 get file object through File Class ,  and you need to use b scheme
        File a = new File("/");
        File b = new File("src/main/java/resource/1.txt");
        File c = new File("./");
        File d = new File(".");
        System.out.println(a.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(b.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(c.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(d.getAbsolutePath());

        System.out.println(" \n\n------------- 3  ----------------");


        //3.  the right answer is put your resource file into resources folder(path is <Your_Project>/src/main/resources)
        // and when your project compiled , the files of resources will be added into target/classes folder
        // and you can get file through your Class

        URL e = Demo.class.getResource("/2.txt");
        URL f = Demo.class.getResource(" 2.txt");
        System.out.println(e.getPath());
//        System.out.println(f.getPath());  your will get a nullPointException here ，detailed information you can get in getResource Method

    }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gO3Ue.png
```