# Java: Pathnames not working once I export to JAR

Tags: java, jar, export

I have exported a project to a runnable JAR in eclipse. There are a few places in my code where I've done the following.

```
String file = "src/Files/...";
loadFile(file); // purely for example
```

Now that the project is in the form of a JAR, those directories don't seem to exist and loading those files fails. I'm pretty sure that the files I'm referencing are packed in the JAR. Do the directories change in any particular way when exported to JAR? Any other ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: You can open your .jar file in a zip program to see if all the files where exported correctly. You also might want to take a look at using classpath:// for your filepaths. This post might also be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423938/java-export-to-an-jar-file-in-eclipse

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to treat them as a classpath resource, not as a local disk file system path. This isn't going to work when you package the files in a JAR and you also don't want to be dependent on the working directory. Files inside a JAR are part of the classpath already.

Assuming that you've a `foo.txt` file in package `com.example`, then you can get an `InputStream` of it as follows

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/example/foo.txt");
// ...
```

Or when you're inside `static` context

```
InputStream input = SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/example/foo.txt");
// ...
```

Or when you want to scan the global classpath

```
InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/com/example/foo.txt");
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [How to read file from relative path in Java project? java.io.File cannot find the path specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844307/how-to-read-text-file-from-relative-path-in-a-project/)
- [getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)

Comment: Thanks. That worked for all the FileStreams. What if I need to use a BufferedWriter?

Comment: @Charlotte: Wrap an InputStreamReader + BufferedReader around your InputStream.

Comment: You can indeed get a `Reader` out of it using `InputStreamReader`. However, you cannot write to it. There are other solutions, depending on the functional requirement. Feel free to ask a new question about this.