# Loading file from the machine

Tags: java

I am loading a file from my machine. Can somebody tell me how to ge it relative to the eclipse workspace path ?

Currently :-

```
DOMConfigurator.configure("C\\abc\\workspace\\resources\\applicationlogger.xml");
```

I want it something like :-

```
DOMConfigurator.configure("\\resources\\applicationlogger.xml");
```

Comment: What do you mean with workspace, Eclipse workspace or current working directory ?

Comment: Hope this gives some hints http://stackoverflow.com/a/3844316/1007273

Comment: So your program will always run in/from Eclipse ?

Comment: Loading files in Java should be done always with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29