# System not able to find the specified file

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to read from a file using Java. But it shows an error saying that system cannot find the specified file, when the file is lying in the same directory as the source file.

below is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class file
{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

      String sCurrentLine;

      br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("RoomList.txt"));

      while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
      } 

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      try {
        if (br != null) br.close();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried all I could but it just doesn't work. Please let me know the reasons for this.
Again I will add that the file RoomList.txt and this code file are in the same directory and even after using fully qualified pathname, it doesn't work. I looked for similar answers for this problem in Stackoverflow and tried them but still it does not seem to be working. Please help.

Comment: I have imported these in the beginning. import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.FileReader;
  import java.io.IOException;

Comment: Can you please post the directory structure ?

Comment: specify the full path to the file. Or print the current working directory. It's not the directory of the source file.

Comment: See the first half of the top answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844307/how-to-read-text-file-from-relative-path-in-a-project

Comment: Try moving the file up one level. Eg. If RoomList.txt is in the level1/src directory, move the file to level1 directory and try.

Comment: C:\semester 2\java\PROJECTS\BookingSystem\RoomList.txt .. this is the text file path. And the path of the source file is C:\semester 2\java\PROJECTS\BookingSystem\file.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not problem in your code, its just that when you do not give any file location The System tries to find the file in the Project root.

Check the image below:

[image]

**EDIT**:  If you are using Eclipse, it should be like this. WHt dont you just paste a screenshot of your project directory.

`C:\CSMAIN\ws\TestFile\src\file.java`

`C:\CSMAIN\ws\TestFile\RoomList.txt`

If you are not using any IDE then, you can create a project and put both the files in the project directory and compile it using command prompt and run it. It works.

Comment: hi, My file is in the project root itself.

Comment: C:\semester 2\java\PROJECTS\BookingSystem\RoomList.txt ... this is the

Comment: C:\semester 2\java\PROJECTS\BookingSystem\RoomList.txt .. this is the text file path. And the path of the source file is C:\semester 2\java\PROJECTS\BookingSystem\file.java

Comment: see the EDIT in my answer

Comment: I have tried what you said. I am not working on eclipse so I created a new folder and put both the files into it.

Comment: I created a new folder and put the source file and the RoomList.txt in that folder and again tried to execute it. I was trying to post an image here, but i dont know how to. I am stuck up with this in the project.

Comment: go to command prompt, navigate to your project folder and then type 
`javac file.java` , press Enter Key and then type `java file`

Comment: is it possible for you to send me your version of running files zipped to my email address. 
P

Comment: pammimeow@gmail.com please send the file

Comment: Hey, thank you so much... its working now.. I checked your files and I was making a mistake of saving my file as RoomList.txt on notepad. Which was creating a full name of RoomList.txt.txt . Thats why program was not able to find the file. Through your directory structure, I found the problem in my file name.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the slashes, try changing your code to:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\semester 2\\java\\PROJECTS\\BookingSystem\\file.java"));
```