# Replace zeros to letter "o" inside words

Tags: java, regex, string

After ocr recognition I have a lot of words where instead of `o` I have `0`. So I want to replace any zeros `inside` words.

Up till now I could do only the following

```
String result ="I don't like th0se books";
result = result.replaceAll("\\w+0\\w*", "o");
System.out.println("RESULT:" + result);
```

My code returns `RESULT:I don't like o books` but I need `RESULT:I don't like those books`. Could anyone say how to do it?

Comment: Use [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Why all correct answers are downvoted

Comment: Well, if you want to specifically match a `0` glued to a *letter*, better use `.replaceAll("(?<=\\p{L})0|0(?=\\p{L})", "o")`. Or, to only replace `0` in between letters - `.replaceAll("(?<=\\p{L})0(?=\\p{L})", "o")`.

Comment: Or [`.replaceAll("(?:(?<=\\p{L})|\\G(?!\\A))0", "o")`](https://regex101.com/r/hPbKms/2) (the initial word position is not covered in this case).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why don't you provide an answer instead of comment . since you are good at regex related question?

Comment: @soorapadman: There are too many people in a downvoting mood here. And the question is not precise, there can be many edge cases not accounted for.

Comment: yes, why instead  of giving a comment provide a valid solution that kill all other invalid answers

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Your solution is the only that works right with `I like th0se b00ks with more that 100 pages`. Make the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: "And the question is not precise" This is what "Too broad" close votes and downvotes are for.

Comment: Mostly your solutions are  are acceptable . i have seen many of your answer

Comment: @Pavel_K; Do I understand it right that you do not need to replace `0` at the start of a word? Only when it is immediately preceded with a letter?

Comment: op wants to replace zeros only if those are wrapped by any kind of word....

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Yes, you are right.

Comment: so this should be the result: ***"...th0se b00ks with 100 pages"*** → ***"...those books with 100 pages"***

Comment: If Casimir's answer works, please accept his solution. It is based on the same principle as [mine](https://regex101.com/r/vBOqke/1).

Comment: Sorry, I really feel bad at posting an answer when so many answers are already given. Casimir's answer must work for you. My previous regex description: - `(?:(?<=\p{L})|\G(?!\A))` - a location in a string that is either immediately preceded with a Unicode letter (`(?<=\p{L})`) or is at the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!\A)`, `\G` also matches the start of a string, thus, the negative lookahead is required here to subtract that possibility)
 - `0` - a `0` character.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: the pattern is good and short, but you need to add an alternative for words that starts with `0` like `0yster`, something like `(?=.\pL)`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: I do not know if I should. OP says they [do not want to handle `0` at the start of a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627208/replace-zeros-to-letter-o-inside-words?noredirect=1#comment76241052_44627208). Or maybe I do not understand the question. I guess it is the latter. Anyway, the initial `0` may start a sentence, and may need to be replaced with `O`, not `o`. Casimir, I leave this question to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a non-word boundary:

```
result = result.replaceAll("\\B0|0\\B", "o");
```

That ensures there is at least one word character before or after the 0.

If you want to prevents zero inside a number to be replaced:

```
result = result.replaceAll("\\b(?!\\d+\\b)(?:0\\B|([^\\W0]+)0)|\\G(?!\\A)0", "$1o");
```

details:

```
\\b              # a word boundary
(?!\\d+\\b)      # negative lookahead: not followed by an integer
(?:
    0\\B         # zero and a non-word boundary (means a word character follows)
  |
    ([^\\W0]+)0  # word characters without zero and a zero
)
|
\\G(?!\\A)0  # a zero contiguous to a previous match (not at the start of the string)
```

*(obviously a regex pattern can't make the difference between an isolated "0" and an isolated "o", or between a "0" and a "o" in a reference number, or a number in scientific notation)*

---

other way: capturing all the opponents

```
result = result.replaceAll("((?>(?:[\\W_]+|\\pL+|\\b\\d+\\b)*))(?:\\B0|0\\B)", "$1o");
```

Comment: This unfortunately also replaces `127610127` with `12761o127`.

Comment: @MarkusBenko: no more.

Comment: for this String: ***"I like th0se b00ks with more that 100 pages";*** the result will be: ***I like those books with more that 1oo pages***

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ : please refresh the page.

Comment: ***"I like th0se b00ks ... 100 pages"***  →  ***I like those b0oks ... 100 pages***

Comment: @AxelH: `hell00000000!` doesn't seem to be problematic. https://regex101.com/r/Es8eX9/2/

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte indeed, I was refering to  ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ comment but it doesn't seems to be a problem actually (I am quite surprise to be honnest ;) )

Answer (score 2):

The regex should be `"0"` not `"\\w+0\\w*"`.

Also, to keep the rest of the words, use capturing groups: `result = result.replaceAll("(\\w+)0(\\w*)", "$1o$2");`

To only replace between "letters" and ignoring numbers for the requirement: `result = result.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z]+)0([a-zA-Z\s0]+)", "$1o$2");`

Answer (score 1):

```
(\B0\B|\B0|0\B)
```

Matches three cases:

- `0` in the middle of a word, e.g. "th0se"
- `0` at the end of a word, e.g. "lid0"
- `0` at the start of a word, e.g. "0thers"

So, `result.replaceAll("(\B0\B|\B0|0\B)", "o");

However this will also replace `I have 101 dogs` with `I have 1o1 dogs`, so you will probably want to further refine your expression, or logic.

While a single regex can be written to achieve this, I feel that it would be simpler and clearer to achieve it in ordinary Java code:

- split the line into tokens (a token can be a chunk of whitespace or a chunk of non-whitespace - you could capture these using the regex `(\s+|\S+)` and a `Matcher`.
- for each token:

  - if it's whitespace, leave it alone
  - if it consists entirely of numbers and symbols, leave alone
  - else `word.replace('0','o')`
  - output token

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use complex regex, You can iterate over string and do the same.

```
char c[] = new char[s.length()];
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
    if(s.charAt(i) == '0'){
        c[i] = 'o';
    }else{
        c[i] = s.charAt(i);
    }
}
 //now convert to string.
s = String.valueOf(c);
```

And for only inside the `words`, you can check following:

```
    String s = "I like th0se b00ks ... 100 pages";
    char c[] = new char[s.length()];
    for(int i=1;i<s.length()-1;i++){
        if(s.charAt(i) == '0' && !Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i+1)) && !Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i-1))){
            c[i] = 'o';
        }else{
            c[i] = s.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    //check corner conditions.
    if(s.length() >=1 && !Character.isDigit(s.charAt(1)) && s.charAt(0) == '0'){
        c[0] = 'o';
    }

    if(s.length() >= 2 &&!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(s.length()-2)) && s.charAt(s.length()-1) == '0'){
        c[s.length()-1] = 'o';
    }

    //now convert to string.
    s = String.valueOf(c);
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Downvote to the answer without even mentioning the reason :(

Comment: This is an unnecessarily complex way to do a simple replace, and completely misses the OP's requirement that they only want to replace `0` when it occurs _inside a word_.

Comment: @khelwood It might be complex way for experts. But I think it is easiest way to do this. And it is doing exactly what is requested by the OP.

Comment: And yes, I agree that it uses an extra array. But time complexity wise it is same as the regex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378455/what-is-the-complexity-of-regular-expression

Comment: **1)** You skip the first and last character **2)** You don't check for every numerical character (this is not restricted to '0' to '9') **3)** Is `#0` is seen as a word or not ?

Comment: Okay updating the answer @AxelH

Answer (score -1):

Try: `result = result.replaceAll("(\\w+)0(\\w+)", "$1o$2");`

Using the input: "I don't like th0se books 00 1230"

You get: "I don't like those books 00 1230"

**EDIT:**

If you use: `result = result.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z]+)0([a-zA-Z]+)", "$1o$2");`, it should work for the "I don't like th0se books 00 1230 1230456" string too.

Comment: duplicate answer

Comment: I like that you changed * into + but on the other hand I'm starting to wonder what the original problem of the code was. What should be the desired behaviour when the OCR matches `P00H`, for example? I can only pause and ponder and wonder what the vague problem statement represented.

Comment: Destructs numbers having zero in them like `1230456`.

Comment: True. I did not think about that. But maybe - as you pointed out - the correct answer depends on the needs of the usage of this algorithm.

Answer (score -3):

You could make use of sed command and pass it to java as an array
sed -i s/0/o/g filename

-i - Changes are saved to new file

s - This is for the search

0 - character to be searched for

o - character to be inserted

To check how to use sed as an array in Java, check this link
[How to run sed command from java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610093/how-to-run-sed-command-from-java-code)

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: @slim ..Thanks. Understood.