# Creating Button with Image in eclipse not working

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to create a button with an image. The API can be found [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FButton.html).

Here is my code:

```
Button settings = new Button(swpContainer, SWT.PUSH);
settings.setText("Settings");
settings.setImage(new Image(null, "/myProject/icons/settings.png"));
```

And here is the exception I am getting..

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: i/o error (java.io.FileNotFoundException:    \myProject\icons\settings.png (The system cannot find the path specified))
```

I am right clicking the image in eclipse and getting the path from the properties.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Button settings = new Button(swpContainer, SWT.PUSH);
settings.setText("Settings");
Image image = new Image(swpContainer.getShell().getDisplay(), 
          getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("icons/settings.png")); //$NON-NLS-1$
settings.setImage(image);
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming `myProject` is your project name, and `icons` is a simple folder in the project, then saying `new Image(null, "icons/settings.png");` is enough.

I also recommend:

- Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844307/how-to-read-text-file-from-relative-path-in-a-project)
- Properly [managing your resources](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/swt-design-2/swt-design-2.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing it for RCP application,try using ImageDescriptor and create image.

```
Image IMG_EXAMPLE = AbstractUIPlugin.imageDescriptorFromPlugin(Activator.PLUGIN_ID,
      "/icons/settings.png").createImage();
```