# java reading xml file from relative path using getResource()

Tags: java, xml, file

I have a xml file placed at location pkgName/src/main/resources/Config.xml

I am trying to read it from java file as

```
package com.xstreamparsing.parsers;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.security.auth.login.Configuration;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

public class XStreamConfigParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        URL url = XStreamConfigParser.class.getResource("config.xml");
        File file = new File(url.getPath());

        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);  // load our xml
```

When i run the program i am unable to read it. i followed the link :

[Reading a file from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27565876/reading-a-file-from-a-relative-path)

Unfortunately i could not succeed. Please suggest best and universal file to read file from java class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> XStreamConfigParser.class.getResource("config.xml");

This will search relative to XStreamConfigParser, in this case in the same package.

Try instead:

```
XStreamConfigParser.class.getResource("/config.xml");
```

This will start looking at the root of your output dir/ jar file.

Alternatively move the file to:

```
src/main/resources/com/xstreamparsing/parsers/config.xml
```

Also make sure sure your using the correct case (`Config.xml` vs `config.xml`).