# Reading an external txt file on main.class

Tags: java, file, stream, external

I have a little question that, I have a blank main class, and the thing is that I want to know how can I read a external `.txt` file located on the package of `main.java` (tests package has `main.java` and `LerDaqui.txt`) and I want to know how can I read and print the content from `LerDaqui.txt` to `main.java`.

Many thanks

BTW I did try to do this, but this is so simple that this is the only what to ask... Either way for some people to not call me lazy and that sort o stuff I got this code at least..

```
package testes;

import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream in  = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("testes/LerDaqui.txt");
        String everything = "nao leu";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testes/LerDaqui.txt"));
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            everything = sb.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
        System.out.println(everything);
    }
}
```

but this gives me `FileNotFound Exception`.....

Comment: I googled it they have give this link 



 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844307/how-to-read-text-file-from-relative-path-in-a-project

Comment: show some effort, what have you already tried. Noone will do your homework for you

Comment: I did google it, did try to solve it but allways the same error.. I'm not lazy keep calm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path you have mentioned in the FileReader is wrong... If file is in the same folder in which your java program is present then the path would be.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("LerDaqui.txt"));
```

Input stream is not necessary.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80292/discussion-on-answer-by-vaibhav-g-reading-an-external-txt-file-on-main-class).