# User entered file paths in Java

Tags: java, file, filepath

I'm writing a text analyzer program that counts words and sentences etc. The user is asked to enter a file to analyze.

Ex.

"Enter a file to analyze : "
"Enter : stuff.txt"

I have the file saved in my project, but only works when I put the full file path, below is how it's handled.

```
public void loadFromFile(String filePath) {
      try {
             theText = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
      } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("could not load file " + filePath);
               e.printStackTrace();
      }          
 }
```

I want to simply write stuff.txt instead of the full file path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read file from relative path in Java project? java.io.File cannot find the path specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844307/how-to-read-file-from-relative-path-in-java-project-java-io-file-cannot-find-th)

Comment: Is there a way I can do this with in this current context

Comment: place your file inside the same package of your class.

Comment: I did, it still won't work.