# Not able to load the file in server using class.getResource()

Tags: java

Im trying to load a .jasper file to generate pdf. The .jasper file is located in the package of the project.(Not externally in the drive) Its working in local, but when I deploy the same project in the server, its not generating the pdf. Im loading the file like

```
 File f = new File(MyUtil.class.getresource("<path of the .jasper>").asFile();
```

Its returning the total path of the file i.e. from D:/workspace/

How can I handle the same in server?

Comment: It is not a file, so you can't create a `File` object from its URL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844307/how-to-read-file-from-relative-path-in-java-project-java-io-file-cannot-find-th

Comment: @RealSkeptic, its a file only and its working in local

Comment: It's a resource. When you pack it in a JAR, it is no longer a file. In local it works because it's not packed into a JAR.