# Failed to read a file in a directory in java

Tags: java, file, io

My project structure is like this:

- Project

  - App

    - x.java
  - files

    - file.txt
  - main.java

I want to access file.txt via x.java.. My code:

```
    File file = new File("file.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    while (sc.hasNextLine())
        out += sc.nextLine();
    if (out.isEmpty()) out = "NOTHING";
```

but gives me NullPointerException.

Comment: You should check if the file exists before using it. if (file.exists()) ...

Comment: @NomadMaker No output lol

Comment: You would have to put a System.out.println() statement where I put the ... This is your program, not mine.

Comment: If `file.txt` is a _resource_ then you must not try to access it via the `File` API. Use the API for accessing resources (e.g. `Class#getResource(String)`, `Class#getResourceAsStream(String)`, etc.).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a plain text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it !
First, I used

```
            File directory = new File("./");
            System.out.println(directory.getAbsolutePath());
```

to detect the whole path.. Then I appended the `directory.getAbsolutePath()` with the filename so it becomes `directory.getAbsolutePath()+"file.txt"`
I used the normal way to read a file by using the scanner and `scanner.readLine()` to read the file !
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40551904/13829149)

Has helped me

Answer (score 0):

If this file is supposed to be part of your app the way class files are (so, effectively read-only, an asset that you pack in with the rest. Think texture maps for games, or icons for user interfaces), use `getResourceAsStream`, as the resource in question may not even be a file (java projects tend to ship as jars, and an entry in a jar is not a file!).

If not, well, then figure out a way to get the full path info into your code, because it's not going to magically figure out that you have a dir structure with "App" and "files", which is non-standard. (the standard route is `src/main/java/pkgname/Type.java` for java files, and `src/main/resources/pkgname/open.png` for assets that just need to be there (don't need compiling).

If you set up a project in your favourite IDE according to this structure and configured using e.g. maven or gradle, then `getResourceAsStream` works during dev time, and also at runtime, even if the resource is inside the jar.

Comment: You may want to show an example of using `getResource[AsStream]`, or at least clarify where those methods exist, as the OP does not appear to know about resources to begin with.

Comment: Null pointer Exception :\

Comment: Then your build system isn't set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you read the file "file.txt", you don't provide with an absolute path so the operating system will look for a file in the current directly. That is the one where your program started.

I get you didn't start the program in the folder "files" but in another folder like maybe the folder "Project". In that case the path to use would be "files/file.txt".