# How to find the working folder of a servlet based application in order to load resources

Tags: servlets, resources, relative-path, absolute-path, working-directory

I write a Java servlet that I want to install on many instances of Tomcat on different servers. The servlet uses some static files that are packed with the war file under WEB-INF. This is the directory structure in a typical installation:

```
- tomcat
-- webapps
--- myapp
---- index.html
---- WEB-INF
----- web.xml
----- classes
------ src
------- .....
----- MY_STATIC_FOLDER
------ file1
------ file2
------ file3
```

How can I know the absolute path of MY_STATIC_FOLDER, so that I can read the static files?

I cannot rely on the "current folder" (what I get in a new File(".")) because it depends on where the Tomcat server was started from, which is different in every installation!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You *could* use [`ServletContext#getRealPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath-java.lang.String-) to convert a relative web content path to an absolute disk file system path.

```
String relativeWebPath = "/WEB-INF/static/file1.ext";
String absoluteDiskPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPath);
File file = new File(absoluteDiskPath);
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
// ...
```

However, if your sole intent is to get an `InputStream` out of it, better use [`ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) instead because `getRealPath()` may return `null` whenever the WAR is not expanded into local disk file system but instead into memory and/or a virtual disk:

```
String relativeWebPath = "/WEB-INF/static/file1.ext";
InputStream input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(relativeWebPath);
// ...
```

This is much more robust than the `java.io.File` approach. Moreover, using `getRealPath()` is considered bad practice.

#### See also:

- [getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)
- [What does servletcontext.getRealPath("/") mean and when should I use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160639/what-does-servletcontext-getrealpath-mean-and-when-should-i-use-it)
- [Where to place and how to read configuration resource files in servlet based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-and-how-to-read-configuration-resource-files-in-servlet-based-app/)
- [Recommended way to save uploaded files in a servlet application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664579/recommended-way-to-save-uploaded-files-in-a-servlet-application/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this 

`String relativeWebPath = "WEB-INF/static/file1.ext";

InputStream input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(relativeWebPath);`

Comment: @BalusC, I didn't see the previous answer while i was logged in, may be both of us posted the answer around the same time... well since your answer has been posted before mine, you deserve an up vote.. :)

Answer (score -2):

I would prefer to use the getResourceaAsStream option to load the resource based on the parent directory.

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/MY_STATIC_FOLDER/file1");
```

Comment: True. Have overseen that the ressources are outside of the class path. Sorry.