# Relative path in java web jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Please help me get relative path in Java web with jsp. I am reading .txt from my project web but where do not know to take this file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The working folder for a Tomcat servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584054/the-working-folder-for-a-tomcat-servlet)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little bit vague but have a look at [`getRealPath`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

Check this [relative and absolute path](http://www.coderanch.com/t/517941/Servlets/java/relative-absolute-path)