# how to get the working directory for a webapp in tomcat?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat5.5

I need to put some settings files in the 'working directory' in order to configure my app.

I have tried puting it in ./WEB-INF/ but did not work, any idea where is the 'working directory'?, and, is it a way to get it programatically?

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The working folder for a Tomcat servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584054/the-working-folder-for-a-tomcat-servlet)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I realize you didn't specifically ask this question maybe this will address your real problem ...

Have you considered putting your config files under WEB-INF/classes ? Many configuration files in a web application are loaded as resources, not as "file" objects. If you put your configuration files under WEB-INF/classes they will be available as resources through the ClassLoader.

EDIT: As a side note, there's a slight danger in putting your config files directly under WEB-INF, as they *may* be exposed to end users by just typing in the correct URL. This depends on other settings in your web container, but it is a real possibility and has happened more than once. Hope you don't do something like keep DB connection info there ...

Comment: This is the correct answer; I've voted it up.  I'd recommend that the OP vote it up and accept it, too.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that there is a way to get working directory in web-app. However you may use `ServletContext.getRealPath()` method to get the real path corresponding to the given virtual path.

Answer (score 4):

The Servlet specification provides your web application with a special [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#TEMPDIR)-specific working directory which has read, write and delete permissions according to the standard security policy of Tomcat:

```
File workingDir = (File)servletContext.getAttribute(ServletContext.TEMPDIR);
```

You will normally create a subdirectory under it for your specific needs since other components, in particular Tomcat itself, will use it for their own needs as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you think you need it, think again.

What if the root of your application is a WAR file and not a "directory"?

Please describe what you think you need it for.  Perhaps there's a better solution to the problem you're having than getting an absolute directory path.

I missed the bit about config files.  The answer below is correct: Put them in WEB-INF/classes; `getResourceAsStream()` is your friend for reading the contents.

This will work with WAR files, exploded or not.  It keeps your web app nice and portable.

Answer (score 0):

To store some config settings without adding `javax.servlet` to my project I built a string to the config directory & my config file with:

```
import java.io.file;

String webAppRoot = System.getProperty( "catalina.base" );
String s = File.separator;
String configDir = webAppRoot + s + "webapps" + s + "myApp" + s + "WEB-INF" + s + "config";
String configFile = configDir + s + "myApp.config";
```

Using `File.separator` ensures this solution works on both Windows & Linux.