# Embedded Derby in Java web application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-web-start

**Description:**

hello! I am creating a `dynamic web project using eclipse` and using embedded `derby` database. Below is the code that i am using to connect/create embedded derby database.

```
private boolean connect() throws Exception{
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        String dbURL = "jdbc:derby:codejava/webdb;create=true";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
        if (conn != null) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Problem**:

When i run the code first time it creates the `database` but when i check the application folder in `webapps` folder in `tomcat`, i found no database folder. Tomcat folder is in my `C:/ Directory` and searching the C:/ directory i found the database folder in my eclipse folder because that's where i start my IDE from if i am not wrong.

**Question**:

How can i create the database folder inside my application folder in `tomcat/webapps` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the eclipse IDE is running Tomcat and derby is run by tomcat it's not inside webapps.

This might help you

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-EclipseDbWebapps/index.html

Answer (score 1):

If you use this format

```
 <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby:d:/DBDIR;create=true"/>
```

you can specify where you want your DB to be.

So I guess that in your case the DB has ended up somewhere relative to `codejava/webdb`

Comment: Thanks, It's working but isn't there any way of create that DB folder relative to project folders?

Comment: @UsmanRiaz Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584054/how-to-find-the-working-folder-of-a-servlet-based-application-in-order-to-load-r

Comment: and then just use this String in my answer above.

Comment: If this answers you question please consider to upvote and/or accept my answer