# FileInputStream not working in web application

Tags: java, file-io, java-io, fileinputstream

We are trying to read a property file in a servlet using fileInputStream.

However we are constanlty getting a file not found exception.

This is the piece of code we are using

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
          File propertyFile = new File("config" + File.separatorChar + "abc.properties");
          try {
          FileInputStream propertyFileStream = new FileInputStream(propertyFile);
                properties.load(propertyFileStream);
                propertyFileStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

While using getResourceAsStream it is working fine.

However we need to understand why FileInputStream is not working.

We have placed the config\abc.properties file in the webInf. We have also tried placing it in the src folder(java classpath), the webContent folder, the WebInf\Classes folder but no success.

Comment: not working? your are not able to get property values?

Comment: It is giving FileNotFOundException

Comment: and i am calling it in a web application

Comment: is it looking for some absolute path? what does the error print?

Comment: This is the error. java.io.FileNotFoundException: config\abc.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: but the same code works in a standalone

Comment: When you want to take from WEB-INF the correct way is getting from ServletContext getResourceAsStream(yourFilePath) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108434/howto-load-a-resource-from-web-inf-directory-of-a-web-archive because **you are using web application**

Comment: ok and if in case i want to use FileInputStream then where do i need to place my file ?

Comment: this guy explains good practices to work with FileInputStream http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584054/how-to-find-the-working-folder-of-a-servlet-based-application-in-order-to-load-r

Answer (score 0):

Resources are not files. They don't live in the file system and they cannot be accessed via `File` or `FileInputStream`.

You should be using `Class.getResource()`.

Comment: but why am i able to access it in a standalone program ?

Comment: Because in the standalone program you aren't using a JAR file, you're accessing classes from the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Try by using

```
  ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("test");
  String VALUE1=resource.getString("KEY1");
  String VALUE2=resource.getString("KEY2");
```

Comment: ok. but why doesnt FileInputStream works....as in why this works for standalone but not in case of web ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code to get resources on web application, because the path must be taken from ServletContext, I think that's what you're looking for, if you are inside Servlet:

```
InputStream is = getContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/yourFolder/abc.properties");
```

to get the full path for your interest:

```
String fullPath = getContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/yourFolder/abc.properties");
```