# configuration properties in webapplication java

Tags: java, servlets

i need to access a configuration file with some properties from a class inside a webapp.

The webapp consist of a servlet that uses another class.

In that class i want to access a configuration file.

Which is the best way?

Comment: are these properties in a .properties file?

Comment: http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=483

Comment: possible duplicate of [where to place properties files in a jsp servlet web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-properties-files-in-a-jsp-servlet-web-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put a properties file under your `WEB-INF/classes` directory. in that way it wil be visible on the classpath, then in your java class you can use :

```
 InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("your_file.properties");
```

Comment: Fine for a quick & dirty "hello world", what about [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection) and testability?

Comment: @jglatre, please elaborate with example, i think this is perfectly fine for normal use.

Comment: It depends on your quality standards. I'd rather declare a `public void setProperties(Properties props)` method, wich lets me use the component in many different environments, for instance: in a JUnit test (I don't have to bother about external files, just create `new Properties()` on the fly), or in a Spring context (I can easily inject values in a XML beans file). Furthermore I can easily swap from one config file name to another, or even change file format, without affecting my component.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Properties` file and read it from `ContextListener` and store it in some application wide accessible map it properties are not too many.

Also you can use `web-param`