# How to obtain an InputStream of a public webcontent resource?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a collection of images packaged in my WAR and I depict them in a `<p:dataGrid>` using `<p:graphicImage>`. The images are located in the `/resources/icons` folder. I want to be able to select an image and save a copy of this image to disk on submit.

How can this be done? How can I get a reference (`InputStream` or whatever) to this image?

Comment: No, actually it is not loading and saving an image. The images are icons packaged with the webapp. A user can select one icon and this icon will need to be saved to a folder on the file system. I can of course duplicate the images in both the webapp and save them in a folder, but I want the image to be copied and then saved to disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this folder structure,

```
YourProject
 |-- src
 |    `-- com
 |         `-- example
 |              `-- BackingBean.java
 |-- WebContent
 |    |-- META-INF
 |    |-- WEB-INF
 |    |-- resources
 |    |    `-- icons
 |    |         `-- foo.png
 |    `-- foo.xhtml
 :
```

You can get it by either [`ExternalContext#getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) which takes webcontent-relative path:

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
InputStream input = externalContext.getResourceAsStream("/resources/icons/foo.png");
// ...
```

Or by [`Resource#getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Resource.html#getInputStream%28%29) wherein `Resource` is obtained from [`ResourceHandler#createResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html#createResource%28java.lang.String%29) which takes a `/resources`-relative path:

```
ResourceHandler resourceHandler = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getResourceHandler();
InputStream input = resourceHandler.createResource("icons/foo.png").getInputStream();
// ...
```

As to selecting the image and passing its path around, just do something like as follows:

```html
<h:graphicImage name="icons/foo.png">
    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.setImage(component.name)}" />
</h:graphicImage>
<h:graphicImage name="icons/bar.png">
    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.setImage(component.name)}" />
</h:graphicImage>
<h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.saveImage}" />
```

#### See also:

- [getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)
- [Where to place and how to read configuration resource files in servlet based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-and-how-to-read-properties-files-in-a-jsp-servlet-web-application)
- [Maven and JSF webapp structure, where exactly to put JSF resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540907/maven-and-jsf-webapp-structure-where-exactly-to-put-jsf-resources/)