# Maven and JSF webapp structure, where exactly to put JSF resources

Tags: jsf, maven

I don't really understand the structure of directories with Maven and JSF webapp.

When I generate project I have this structure :

```
src
|_ main
   |_ java
   |_ resources
   |_ webapp
      |_ WEB-INF 
         |_ web.xml
      |_ index.xhtml
```

I want to include some resources :

- javascript file
- css file
- images
- i18n files

I can include i18n files inside `src/main/resources` but not anywhere and I can include JS file, CSS file and images inside `src/main/webapp/resources` but not anywhere...

I didn't find very clear rules on the web about directories structure with JSF and Maven.

What are the rules please ?

Thanks

Comment: The fact that you're using JSF isn't very relevant, the end result will be a standard WAR - in which the content of webapp will be the root (and thus the content of webapp excluding WEB-INF is what will be the web tree).  So, maybe start with the [Maven WAR plugin doc](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) and [the basic structure of a WAR file](http://www.openscope.net/2010/01/25/war-deployment-file-structure/)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

JSF resources which are to be referenced by `<h:outputStylesheet>`, `<h:outputScript>` and `<h:graphicImage>` (thus, CSS/JS/images), should end up in `/resources` folder of the public webcontent, there where the `/WEB-INF` and `/META-INF` folders also are.

Thus, you've to put them in `/src/main/webapp/resources`.

```
src
 `-- main
      |-- java
      |-- resources
      `-- webapp
           |-- resources
           |    |-- css
           |    |    `-- style.css
           |    |-- images
           |    |    `-- logo.png
           |    `-- js
           |         `-- script.js
           |-- WEB-INF 
           |    `-- web.xml
           `-- index.xhtml
```

Those i18n files (I assume you technically meant resource bundle files) have ultimately to end up in a package in `/WEB-INF/classes`. The `/src/main/resources` is intented for non-class files which are supposed to end up in `/WEB-INF/classes`, you should put them in there. Assuming a bundle base name of `com.example.i18n.text`, provide them as such:

```
src
 `-- main
      |-- java
      |-- resources
      |    `-- com
      |         `-- example
      |              `-- i18n
      |                   |-- text.properties
      |                   |-- text_en.properties
      |                   |-- text_es.properties
      |                   `-- text_nl.properties
      :
```

#### See also:

- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template)
- [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: You're welcome. I think the biggest source of confusion is in the same naming convention of the "resources" folder and completely different purposes for each of them.

Comment: Yes it is. Moreover it's my first JSF webapp and Maven use

Answer (score 2):

The best location for css/images etc is in src/main/webapp/images or src/main/webapp/css/ etc. Currently there is no location src/main/webapp/resources. The src/main/resources folder is intended for resources (property files etc.) which should be filtered or should be located into WEB-INF/classes folder. So usualy you don't like to filter images and css files. Take a look into the [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) documentation which gives some hints and configuration examples.
The best approach seemed to be to put everything into src/main/webapp/FOLDER which shouldn't be filtered in anyway otherwise you should put it into [src/main/resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) and you can control the filtering and the replacements

Comment: thank you, but when I put images, css and js files into webapp folder, I can only access images not js and css files. Surely, it is because I use h:outputStylesheet and h:outputScript. I'll look for this tag to understand well why.