# Add/import javascript library into JSF+Maven project

Tags: javascript, jsf, maven, three.js

I'm using a javascript library to develop a interface with 3D graphics in a JSF project with Maven and I was wondering if there is a way to add/import this js library into my project without having to move/copy all the js files into the webapp/resources directory. I already tried to do it with the tags  and  within the  tag of the pom.xml file but it didn't work.

The error is produced by this line:

```
<h:outputScript name="Three.js" />
```

It says the resource is not found.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'm using JFS 2.1

Comment: Please mention which version of JSF you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Maven is a tool for among others managing java dependencies, and building your application. It is used to produce a java application. As you understand, JavaScript runs on the client side in a web application, while java runs on the server side. But sometimes Maven *can* import JS resources as an integral part of a java library. PrimeFaces is one example.

As to the resource management within a JSF application, including JS scripts, you've basically got two ways:

1. Import external scripts with a plain HTML `<script>` element. This way you don't need to do any imports and just reference an external to JSF script.
2. Import internal scripts with a `<h:outputScript>`. This way, resources and in particular your scripts, will be imported from within a web application, most possibly, but not necessarily, from within your `resources` folder. Otherwise, you can access scripts from *maven imported artifacts*, like PrimeFaces, that include JS resources as well. In this case you need to specify `library` attribute of `<h:outputScript>`.

To my knowledge, no java library ships with Three.js included, so your best bet is to either reference an external script, or import it within your JSF project. But if I'm wrong - just go ahead and incude that library via Maven to be able to reference it in your views.

Comment: By the way, I'm using RichFaces.

The thing is that I want to import all the js files into my JSF project with the outputScript tag including the library property but I don't know how to do it without copying all of them into the reosurce library. What should I do? Should I write 

    <h:outputScript ... library="..\..\..\JSdirectory"> 

until it reaches the directory where I actual have the js files?

You said that I can import scripts and not necessarily from within my source folder and that's my problem, I don't know how to import scripts from a different directory.

Comment: Go through excellent [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used) and [Maven and JSF webapp structure, where exactly to put JSF resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540907/maven-and-jsf-webapp-structure-where-exactly-to-put-jsf-resources) answers before proceeding any further.

Comment: Well, after a few hours reading those links and other documentation, I couldn't find a real solution so I'll finally copy all the js files into the webapp/resources directory but thanks anyway.

Comment: Basically it's the most straight way and IMO the only proper one.