# image is not showing up with primefaces commandbutton - icon attribute

Tags: primefaces, commandbutton

Image is not showing up with `primefaces commandbutton` - icon attribute

I tried below styles but of no use

```
1.  .ui-icon-csv{
background-image: url("#{resource['/images/csv.jpg']}") !important;
}

2.  .ui-icon-csv{
background-image: url("#{resource['images/csv.jpg']}") !important;
}
```

css file path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
```

Project structure: Not able to post image

```
projectname ->
             css
             images
             js
             index.jsp etc
```

There is no resource folder in project. So, It is giving problem with image path for icon

Kindly let me know how to resolve this???

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the built WAR-file your image should be at `resources/images/csv.jpg`. JSF specification defines that there must be the `resources` folder.

Your project structure is up to you and/or your build tool. E.g., for Maven see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13541195/1341535).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time Golovanov. I agree with you. There should be resources folder but this project structure is created like that without resources folder and I can't change it now. Can you please let me know is there any workaround???