# Resources CSS does not works in JSF working in Intellij IDEA

Tags: css, intellij-idea, jsf-2

In minimal application I can use CSS

**VERSIONS**

```
IDEA 2018.2
jsf-app and jsf-impl version 2.2.5
javax.servlet-api 3.1.0
javax.servlet.jsp-api 2.3.3
```

Hear is project **structure** and **index.htnl**

[image]

The page **result**:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Image also doesn't works. It seams problem in **resources** folder

[image]

and **result**

[image]

**Added** explicitly added to POM.xml following *build* part, but also NOT helped. Question WHY?

```
<build>
    <finalName>Spring Examples</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: Before this post I search the problem solution but does not found any necessary answers (all I found) vich solved problem. I think this is issue related IntelliJ IDEA  and JSF implementation. I tried many examples but get the same problem. Please give the solution which found, may be that one I tried. hank you very much.

Comment: Look at the top of your question.

Comment: Sorry, but I understand what you mean. If  you about "In minimal application I can use CSS " so yes, this is minimal application what works in IntelliJ. In your link it don't related in Intellij specific problem.

Comment: @Kukeltje OK, resources folder does not work, so WHY  IDEA auto generate a project directory which is in fact  does not work.

Comment: Scroll to top. There's a yellow box which says: "**This question already has an answer here**: _How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?_". The last line is a link. Click on it. You'll be redirected to the duplicate question which contains the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @BalusC  I of course clicked and entered and read but IDEA specific information doesn't found.Sorry.

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan: Check the **location where to put these resources** in the duplicate above. Read carefully, not quickly... It is all 100% in there

Comment: @Kukeltje I tried all possible places, but it is don't wont to help me :). I think that resources folder does not work in my project. (but it recourse icon exists).

Comment: What 'all possible places'? I don't see any other place then `src/main/resources' for the css and the image in your project. And according to the duplicate that is not the right place... All the info is in the **Folder Structure** in the duplicate.

Comment: @Kukeltje  Of course at first `src/main/resources` folder I tried. And you if know any existing page which helps I will deleted this page as duplicate, but for now I haven't  find solution.

Comment: Wow... From the duplicate (bold mine): _"Drop the CSS/JS/image files in /resources folder of the **public webcontent** as below (just create one if not already exist at the **same level** as /WEB-INF and /META-INF)."_  and _"In case of Maven, it should be in /main/webapp/resources and thus **not** /main/resources"_   So /src/main/resources is wrong and /src/main/web/resources won't work either (unless you have a specific web root config in your maven pom). And the reference in it to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540907/maven-and-jsf-webapp-structure-where-exactly-to-put-jsf-resources

Comment: Great it works. A couple of things. In Stackoverflow answers belong in answers, not in edited questions. And regarding your 'numbered answer parts', 1: Already in the duplicate. Next time read a little better. 2: Totally not needed, this makes the files in that folder from the source end up in the classes folder in the target. 3: If you change the api, you also need to change the impl otherwise yes, there is a problem. Totally unrelated to this question. I reverted the question back to the original one before the answer