# Is it possible to open JSF page with Payara Micro?

Tags: jsf, payara-micro

I tried to start Payara Micro server. Firsly, I wrote it as java code, like this.

```
    PayaraMicro payaraMicro = PayaraMicro.getInstance();
    payaraMicro.bootStrap();
```

It run, but with 404 error (I don't know why also). After I also run jar file in command line and it was the same result.
What I want it's to open page in browser, when my server is deployed. I need to open page with .jsf extension (or at lease html page with simple "Hello world!"). Is it possible? Am I need to write it like configuration in xml file or run from command line?

Notes:
https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/documentation/payara-micro/appendices/cmd-line-opts.html It seems that there is no info in this documentation, or I don't understand something...

Here my example https://github.com/dasha-buzovska/payaraMicro

Comment: .. and it does run on a standard Payara? Also, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: https://github.com/dasha-buzovska/payaraMicro here all project

Comment: I didn't try standard Payara, because I need exactly Payara Micro.

Comment: Code should be inline in [mcve] flavour, not in an external system

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540907/maven-and-jsf-webapp-structure-where-exactly-to-put-jsf-resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you had the webapp folder in the wrong place (it should be under main, not under main/resources) and you didn't have a web.xml which enables the faces servlet.

I created a PR for you which builds a working app. I also changed the packaging to war as I'm not so familiar with the uberjar packaging. HTH!