# Split web.xml context-param into separate config file

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, web.xml, configuration-files, context-param

I have too many context-parameters inside web.xml, which I would like to put in a separate config-file.

```
.....
<context-param>
        <param-name>SYSTEM.UPLOADS.DIR</param-name>
        <param-value>/home/youfaces/uploads/</param-value>
</context-param>
......
```

In a managed class I want to read these params usually like this:

```
String XYZ   = servletContext.getInitParameter("param name");
```

Is it possible to put this params in separate config-file and reading it via  `.getInitParameter(..`? if yes where/how to declare it in web.xml exactly?

Every tip/idea is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892480/loading-properties-file-in-init-of-servlet-without-using-context-param-tag-in

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar, thanks for the link. but what i need is any idea on how to change the configuration not the Code itself. its a big project, coded from many developers, and these params is used every where in the projekt, so changing Java Code is not an Option.

Answer (score 3):

With Servlet 3.0 and Tomcat 7 you can use [web-fragments](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_web_fragment) to have many configuration files. Tomcat will load and build all fragments to one web.xml on runtime.