# read .properties file in static code of a JSF web application

Tags: jsf, properties

I would like to get DB connection parameters from a properties file in a static block. The properties file location is `WEB-INF/classes/db.properties`.

I will prefer to use `getResourceAsStream()` method. I have tried many ways, but they all returned `null`.

```
private static Properties prop = new Properties();
static{
    try {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) facesContext.getExternalContext().getContext();
        InputStream inputStream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/db.properties"); 
        InputStream is = prop.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/db.properties");
        if(inputStream!=null){//it is null
            prop.load(inputStream);
        }
        if(is!=null){//it is null
            prop.load(is);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: http://jaitechwriteups.blogspot.ca/2007/01/how-to-read-properties-file-in-web.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to place and how to read configuration resource files in servlet based application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-and-how-to-read-configuration-resource-files-in-servlet-based-app)

Answer (score 1):

As Thufir wrote in a comment, there is a nice tutorial from reading properties from Java code: http://jaitechwriteups.blogspot.ca/2007/01/how-to-read-properties-file-in-web.html

```
/** 
 * Some Method 
 *  
 * @throws IOException 
 *  
 */  
public void doSomeOperation() throws IOException {  
    // Get the inputStream  
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader()  
            .getResourceAsStream("myApp.properties");  

    Properties properties = new Properties();  

    System.out.println("InputStream is: " + inputStream);  

    // load the inputStream using the Properties  
    properties.load(inputStream);  
    // get the value of the property  
    String propValue = properties.getProperty("abc");  

    System.out.println("Property value is: " + propValue);  
}
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer/explain OP's concrete question/problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
InputStream inputStream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/db.properties");
```

This attempt expects the file to be in `/WebContent/db.properties`.

```
InputStream is = prop.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/db.properties");
```

This attempt expects it to be in at least the same archive (JAR) as the `java.util.Properties` class.

Neither of those attempts reads the file which you've placed in `/WEB-INF/classes/db.properties`. You can fix this problem in basically 2 ways.

1. Move it directly in the `/WEB-INF` folder as `/WEB-INF/db.properties` and load it as follows:

   ```
   InputStream input = externalContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/db.properties");
   ```

   *(note that you don't need to haul the `ServletContext` from under the JSF's hoods; there's already a delegate method for that)*
2. Load it relative to the class which is also present in `/WEB-INF/classes`, e.g. the current managed bean class.

   ```
   InputStream input = Bean.class.getResourceAsStream("/db.properties");
   ```

   Or just use the context classloader, it has access to everything.

   ```
   InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("db.properties");
   ```

   *(note the lack of the `/` prefix)*

#### See also:

- [Where to place and how to read configuration resource files in servlet based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-configuration-properties-files-in-a-jsp-servlet-web-application/2161583#2161583)