# Accessing relative files in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am using a third party library in my WebApp on tomcat.

The problem is that a class of that third party library requires initialization with an XML file

```
LibraryClass lb = new LibraryClass("file path.xml");
```

So where should I put files in tomcat directories in order to be able to access them from inside the webapp??

(Note that the class requires a `String` for the absolute path, not a `FileStream` for example)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the file to be downloadable, make it a resource by placing it somewhere in your Java source directory and let it be copied into WEB-INF/classes. Then use `ServletRequest.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classes/...")` to turn the relative path into an absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep them under WEB-INF/classes folder.You can see complete discussion about this here:
[Where to place configuration properties files in a JSP/Servlet web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-configuration-properties-files-in-a-jsp-servlet-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answers, I agree that the best place for these files is inside your `war` bundle. Unlike the other answers, I would *not* recommend putting the file in `WEB-INF/classes` as that directory is for *class* files, not XML files.

If `path.xml` is located in the war's root, then you can get access to it with something like this:

```
String servletDirectoryPath = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("");
String xmlConfigurationFileName = "path.xml";
File xmlConfigurationFile = new File(servletDirectoryPath, xmlConfigurationFileName);
initializeThirdPartyLibrary(xmlConfigurationFile);
```

Comment: It is for classes *and resources.* Putting it in the root as you suggest means it can be downloaded directly, which is not desirable.