# How can I get the directory of my deployed web application?

Tags: servlets, struts2

How to get current working directory for struts2 web application?

```
String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String currentDir = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
```

return `/usr/share/tomcat`.

I need path to web application, so I could read a file from war.

Comment: Related: [Where to place configuration properties files in a JSP/Servlet web application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-configuration-properties-files-in-a-jsp-servlet-web-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the ServletContext's real path: [`ServletContext.getRealPath(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29)

That said, why do you want to read a file that's in a war file, and why do you want to do it this way?

Prefer putting the file on the classpath and using `getResourceAsStream`:

- [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)
- [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I want to get current directory to open db.properties file. But I have found another problem: it is possible to view in web browser contents of db.properties file and db password. How to limit access to db.properties file ? How to get db.properties using getResourceAsStream ?

Comment: @EkaYuda The only way it would be possible to access a property file directly is if it's in a publicly-accessible location (something deployed, but not under `WEB-INF`) and it's not filtered. It would be Really Weird to put a property file in a place it could be access directly. To get the file using getResourceAsStream you follow every tutorial in the world on how to use getResourceAsStream.

Comment: So, I need to put db.properties in WEB-INF ?

Comment: @EkaYuda If you want it on the classpath, it should be in `WEB-INF/classes`, or a jar in `WEB-INF/lib`.