# Load properties file in Servlet/JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, properties

I've created a `jar` from my `Java project` and wanted to use the same jar in a `JSP Servlet Project`. I'm trying to load a property file let say sample.properties from my `JSP Servlet Project` kept in `WEB/properties/sample.properties` which should be read by a class in the `jar`.I'm using the following code wriiten in a class of jar to access it.

```
Properties prop=new Properties();
prop.load(/WEB-INF/properties/sample.properties);
```

But each time I'm getting `fileNotFound exception`.
Please suggest me the solution.

Here is the structure

```
WEB-INF
      |
       lib
          |
           myproject.jar
                       |
                        myclass (This class needs to read sample.properties)
      |
       properties
                 |sample.properties
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-configuration-properties-files-in-a-jsp-servlet-web-application

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `/WEB-INF` folder is **not** part of the classpath. So any answer here which is thoughtless suggesting [`ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) will **never** work. It would only work if the properties file is placed in `/WEB-INF/classes` which is indeed part of the classpath (in an IDE like Eclipse, just placing it in Java source folder root ought to be sufficient).

Provided that the properties file is really there where you'd like to keep it, then you should be getting it as web content resource by [`ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) instead.

Assuming that you're inside a `HttpServlet`, this should do:

```
properties.load(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/properties/sample.properties"));
```

*(the `getServletContext()` is inherited from the servlet superclass, you don't need to implement it yourself; so the code is as-is)*

But if the class is by itself not a `HttpServlet` at all, then you'd really need to move the properties file into the classpath.

#### See also:

- [Where to place and how to read configuration resource files in servlet based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-configuration-properties-files-in-a-jsp-servlet-web-application/2161583#2161583)

Comment: All good answers - devil's advocate through; if you're planning on storing sensitive info in said properties file (e.g. API username / password / secret key etc..) then it probably shouldn't be in your code base; as then it will be under version control - which is just another way for folks to get a hold of your info; in this case store it outside of your document root

Answer (score 6):

Try to put sample.properties under `src` folder, and then

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myprop.properties"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Move your properties files under `WEB-INF/classes`. Then load it as following:

`prop.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("sample.properties"));`

You can put it into sub-directory under `classes` as well. In this case change the call to `getResourceAsStream()` accordingly.

To be safer in multi-classloader system you can use `Thread.getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` instead.

To make the properties file to arrive to `classes` folder of your war file you have to put it under `resources` folder in your project (if you are using maven) or just under `src` folder if you do not use maven-like directory structure.

Comment: I did it by using `InputStream inStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("../properties/DBDetails.properties");
prop.load(inStream)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 InputStream inStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                     .getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/properties/sample.properties");
```

Then, load(InputStream) it into a Properties object:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(inStream);
```

Comment: I tried this,but it didn't work.It throws the same exception.

Comment: shouldn't it be `WEB-INF/properties/sample.properties` instead of `/WEB-INF/properties/sample.properties`?

Comment: add your properties file in the jar file from where you are trying to access the file,i.e. project which is in jar file.Or place the sample.properties in C:/D: or somewhere else and give full path eg C:/sample.properties.

Answer (score 0):

it may not work If you are try to  load the properties from jsp/servlet. Write a utility class to read properties  and package along with jar file. copy the properties file into same package as of utility.

```
 Class Utility{
    Properties properties=null;
    public void load() throws IOException{
        properties.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("sample.properties"));
    }
    public Object get(String key) throws IOException{
        if (properties==null){
            load();
        }
        return properties.get(key); 
    }
  }
```

Now use this utility class from servlet to read the property values. May be you can  define the class as singleton for better practice

Cheers
Satheesh