# how to access property files in java ee

Tags: java, jsp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Load properties file in Servlet/JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507016/load-properties-file-in-servlet-jsp)

I was wondering how to access a property file from a Java class,where this project is done using Java EE,because the stacktrace keeps giving me this message(is it because that folder is inaccessible?).The question is: How to access a property file from a Java class in Java EE?

Here is the code:

In UserClient.java:

```
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.load(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/L31207/Desktop/FYPJ/OpenCalais/MarcusFYPJ"));
        String[][] categories = fetchArrayFromPropFile("content", config);
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\L31207\Desktop\FYPJ\OpenCalais\MarcusFYPJ (Access is denied)
```

Comment: Is `MarcusFYPJ` a file and present in `C:\Users\L31207\Desktop\FYPJ\OpenCalais` directory?

Comment: It is a folder and it is present

Comment: You need to be reading a file, I think, not a folder.

Comment: so i assume that this class is running on a application server. did you check the server has access to the file? i have done this without any issue.

Comment: I think that is the problem. Please provide the full path of your properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you are using a program to open the file doesn't mean you can completely ignore the security measures your operating system has in place.  The "user" running the program doesn't have permissions to open this file.

That is why your "reason" in the stack trace is "Access is denied".  Perhaps you can actually open this file, but *your program* running as *the user it is running as* cannot.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:Silly me,what Yogendra Singh says is right.I did not specify the file name,only the folder name.