# .properties file is not searched by jar when it is run on cmd

Tags: java, jar, cmd

When I run the jar on `cmd` it do not search the `.properties` file and hence the complete functionality is not established. My `.properties` file is under the `/src` folder. How can I resolve this issue?

```
try {
    // Loads the constants.properties file
        InputStream constantPropFile = 
            ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream
 ("/account.properties");
        constantProp.load(constantPropFile);
    }  catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: And how is your class path set? See parameter -cp or -classpath. Could you describe where is your class stored and where is your properties file stored?

Comment: What is the specific error you got?

Comment: how do i need to check the classpath?

Comment: You said your properties file is located in the `/src` folder. Is your output folder during compile time the same as the `/src` folder? If you have a different output folder for the classes did you copy the properties file to the `classes` (output folder of the compile process) folder?  Or did you expicitly add your properties file to the jar? You can check of the jar contains your properties file by `jar t your.jar`. Another option is to add your `/src` (the directory where the properties file is located) by `java -cp <dir> -jar your.jar `

Comment: You may refer [this][1] question. It looks similar.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19424308/add-properties-file-to-build-path-of-runnable-jar

Comment: D:\Postcard_workspace_new\Postcard_workspace\ConfigMigrationUtility\bin;D:\Postcard_workspace_new\Postcard_workspace\ConfigMigrationUtility\lib\org.apache.commons.io.jar
This is my classpath and my properties file are in D:\Postcard_workspace_new\Postcard_workspace\ConfigMigrationUtility\src

Comment: My output folder has different location as that of /src folder. Also i have not explicitly added the properties file to my jar. Also I tried your -cp command given above it throwed an exception as "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at configmigrator.utility.ConfigMigrator.main(ConfigMigrator.java:15)"

Comment: you can watch that:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775303/read-properties-file-outside-jar-file

Comment: @Perez I have already gone through it. It do not give my solution

Comment: I think, the purpose of a properties file is to be able to edit it, so I think that  must be the solution, if you get the file inside the jar, there is no diference between your properties and a constants java class.

Comment: My jar is working well on local systems. But when I run it on Virtual Machine I dont get required output