# why i'm getting this error of HTTP Status 500?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, nullpointerexception

I've created a simple JSP page and made a Servlet called `UserController.java` which is inside the package `com.pro3.controller`. In jsp page I have a form with get method. When I submit the form it fails with following exception:

HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.pro3.controller.UserController

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Exception report

message javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.pro3.controller.UserController

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.pro3.controller.UserController
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:412)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)


root cause 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.pro3.controller.UserController
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:709)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:680)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:62)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)


root cause 

java.lang.NullPointerException
    java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:418)
    java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:337)
    java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:325)
    com.pro3.util.DbUtil.getConnection(DbUtil.java:26)
    com.pro3.dao.UserDao.<init>(UserDao.java:19)
    com.pro3.controller.UserController.<init>(UserController.java:27)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:709)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:680)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:62)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

Anyone help me out this problem.

```
public class DbUtil 
{
    public static Connection connection = null;
    
    public static Connection getConnection()
    {
        if(connection!=null)
            return connection;
        else
        {
            try
            {
                Properties prop=new Properties();
                InputStream inputStream=DbUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/db.properities");
                prop.load(inputStream);
                
                String driver=prop.getProperty("driver");
                String url=prop.getProperty("url");
                String user=prop.getProperty("user");
                String password=prop.getProperty("password");
                
                Class.forName(driver);
                connection=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
                
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
```

This is Null Pointer Exception:

```
public class UserController extends HttpServlet 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static String INSERT_OR_EDIT="/user.jsp";
    private static String LIST_USER="/listuser.jsp";
    private UserDao dao;
    
    public UserController() 
    {
        super();
        dao = new UserDao();
    }
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
        {
            String forward="";
            String action = request.getParameter("action");
            
            if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete"))
            {
                int userId=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userid"));
                dao.deleteUser(userId);
                forward=LIST_USER;
                request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());
            }
            else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit"))
            {
                forward=INSERT_OR_EDIT;
                int userId=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userid"));
                User user=dao.getUserById(userId);
                request.setAttribute("user", user);
            }
            else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("listUser"))
            {
                forward=LIST_USER;
                request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());
            }
            else
            {
                forward=INSERT_OR_EDIT;
            }
            RequestDispatcher view=request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
            view.forward(request, response);
        }
        
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
        {
        User user=new User();
        user.setFirstName(request.getParameter("firstname"));
        user.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastname"));
       try
       {
           Date dob = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").parse(request.getParameter("dob"));
           user.setDob(dob);
       }
       catch(ParseException e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
        user.setEmail(request.getParameter("email"));
        String userid=request.getParameter("userid");
        if(user==null||userid.isEmpty())    
        {
            dao.addUser(user);
        }
        else
        {
            user.setUserid(Integer.parseInt(userid));
            dao.updateUser(user);
        }
        RequestDispatcher view=request.getRequestDispatcher(LIST_USER);
        request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());
        view.forward(request, response);
     }
}
```

---

Pablo Lozano: He found some error, and then ill do it then, now i getting this kind of error.

> HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- type

Exception report message java.lang.NullPointerException

> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
> from fulfilling this request.

exception

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:430)
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)

rootcause

java.lang.NullPointerException

> com.pro3.dao.UserDao.getAllUsers(UserDao.java:74)
> com.pro3.controller.UserController.doGet(UserController.java:51)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
> org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:709)
> org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:680)
> org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:62)
> org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DbUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/db.properities");
```

Try to write `db.properties` instead of `db.properities`

Comment: Your are trying to find a properties file, but the name of the file is misspelled

Answer (score 0):

It says `java.lang.NullPointerException`, so there is an object, which is not instantiated. I assume you are using `java.lang.Propertis#load(InputStream)` in your `com.pro3.util.DbUtil.getConnection` so you are probably instantiating it (if at all) in a wrong way.

So, you can't use getResourceAsStream from your DbUtils.class (I assume, if you only put your ptoperties into the same package, it will work). Please [find out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507016/load-properties-file-in-servlet-jsp) how to properly load properties in Servlet.

Comment: First of all please share your `DbUtil.getConnection()` method, so that we can find out how do you create an `InputStream`.