# Reading properties file in Java web application

Tags: java, servlets, properties-file, servletcontextlistener

I am currently using a `ServletContextListener` to set the paths of JSPs in a web application. The paths are stored as context parameters in `web.xml` and retrieved by the listener:

```
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {        
        ServletContext sc = sce.getServletContext();                           
        sc.setAttribute("urlOfThisPage", sc.getInitParameter("urlOfThisPage"));   
        sc.setAttribute("urlOfThatPage", sc.getInitParameter("urlOfThatPage"));
```

In the application servlets, the path of a particular JSP can easily be retrieved from `ServletContext`.

My question relates to handling a properties file in the same way. I read a lot about this on other StackOverflow pages like [2161045](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-configuration-properties-files-in-a-jsp-servlet-web-application).

Am I correct in assuming that the properties file should be read by a listener and stored in `ServletContext` using a `Property` object? but then if this is the case, how would I retrieve a particular property from the properties file?

At the moment I am using this sort of code in my servlets to get the value of an attribute from `ServletContext`.

```
String url = (String) sc.getAttribute("urlOfThisPage");  // Use ServletContext to get JSP's URL.
```

But I am not sure how to extend this to accessing a properties file.

I have tried the following in the `ServletContextListener`:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("name", "Akechi Jinsai");
    sc.setAttribute("properties", properties);
```

And in a servlet, using code:

```
   ServletContext sc = request.getSession().getServletContext();        
   Properties properties = (Properties) sc.getAttribute("properties");
   System.out.println("Here: " + properties.getProperty("name"));
```

"Here: Akechi Jinsai" is displayed but is there a better way of getting a single property in a servlet without looking up things in this way?

Comment: "Am I correct in assuming that the properties file should be read by a listener" - no.

Comment: Then where in a web application would be the best place to read the properties file and store it?

Comment: The properties file should be read during startup and kept in memory. It may be stored in a utility class (could be singleton) as a static field, for example.

Comment: Or through the init method of a servlet I suppose?

Comment: You can use both `getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(...)` (if the file is in the classpath) as well as use absolute path - but I don't see any connection to that fact with a property file "should be read by a listener". A listener listens to events and runs callbacks on the occurrence of those events - it has nothing to do with loading a properties file.

Comment: True, there is no absolute need to use a listener but I am thinking of  using a listener of the right type, i.e. a ServletContextListener, to  set the properties up when the ServletContext starts. Or to call a class that can do it. I have revised the question to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply load the properties file in Servlet and move the values into `HashMap` and store it as application attribute. Now access it in JSP using [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html).

Read more about [Load properties file in Servlet/JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507016/load-properties-file-in-servlet-jsp).

---

Sample code:

JSP: (Different ways to access the map)

```
<c:forEach items="${map}" var="entry">
    Key="${entry.key}" Value=${entry.value}
</c:forEach>

URL Of This Page = ${map.urlOfThisPage }
URL Of That Page = ${map.urlOfThatPage }


URL Of This Page = ${map['urlOfThisPage'] }
URL Of That Page = ${map['urlOfThatPage'] }
```

ServletContextListener

```
public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sc) {

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ServletContext sc = sce.getServletContext();
        // load the properties file if needed
        // read the path from web.xml as init parameter 

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("urlOfThisPage", sc.getInitParameter("urlOfThisPage"));
        map.put("urlOfThatPage", sc.getInitParameter("urlOfThatPage"));

        sc.setAttribute("map", map);
    }

}
```

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>urlOfThisPage</param-name>
    <param-value>url</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>urlOfThatPage</param-name>
    <param-value>url</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.x.y.z.MyServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: I would use a properties object instead of  map, but the basic principle is the same.

Comment: Properties extends `Hashtable`. Yes the basic concept is same.

Comment: It's along the lines of what I want anyway.

Comment: Should I code for you using properties file as well or you can do it by simple using `Hashtable` instead of `HashMap` in my code.

Comment: If I'm right all I need to do is load the properties using something like `properties.load(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/properties/sample.properties"))`. I am assuming that after this the properties would be loaded into an attribute in `ServletContext` and then in a servlet, a particular property would be looked up as my code sample above in the question demonstrates? Or is there a better way to get a property in a servlet?

Comment: First read the path from web.xml as I suggested rather than hard coding it in listener class itself.

Comment: Of course, I just copied the code from another page.

Comment: That's OK what about JSP? How to access the property in JSP page?

Comment: I am trying to avoid using any properties in the JSPs. All the paths to JSPs are stored in `web.xml` anyway and read by the listener and stored in `ServletContext` attributes. So that's why I thought to use an attribute in `ServletContext` for the properties. The JSP paths could become properties as well. But is storing the properties as an attribute in `ServletContext` the best way of doing things

Comment: You can simply create a static member of type Properties in ServletContextListner class itself and access it statically. There is no need to put in the context at all.

Comment: A static instance of Property? Good idea. I never thought of that.

Comment: It will be always available to the application because it's initialized at the application start-up.

Comment: Yes. and only ever be read once upon startup. I like it!-) Many thanks Braj.